# How to define an empty object in PHP

Tags: php, object

with a new array I do this:

```
$aVal = array();

$aVal[key1][var1] = "something";
$aVal[key1][var2] = "something else";
```

Is there a similar syntax for an object

```
(object)$oVal = "";

$oVal->key1->var1 = "something";
$oVal->key1->var2 = "something else";
```

Comment: `$var = (object) (boolean) (string)  (int) (array) new StdClass;`  You know, just to be safe.

Comment: Google has indexed this question title as: `Arrays - How to define an empty object in PHP`. Has nothing to do with arrays

Answer (score 1001, accepted):

```
$x = new stdClass();
```

A [comment in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#92123) sums it up best:

> stdClass is the default PHP object.
>   stdClass has no properties, methods or
>   parent. It does not support magic
>   methods, and implements no interfaces.
>
> When you cast a scalar or array as
>   Object, you get an instance of
>   stdClass. You can use stdClass
>   whenever you need a generic object
>   instance.

Comment: $o=(object)NULL; -- If an object is converted to an object, it is not modified. If a value of any other type is converted to an object, a new instance of the stdClass built-in class is created. If the value was NULL, the new instance will be empty. Arrays convert to an object with properties named by keys, and corresponding values. For any other value, a member variable named scalar will contain the value.

Comment: I just say `stdClass` in my head as "standard class"

Comment: @zombat, What's with the brackets `stdClass()`?

Comment: I think PHP version should be >= 5.4 to use this method

Comment: If you encounter "not found": `new \stdClass();` [PHP Namespace Doc](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php)

Comment: @IvanCastellanos could you explain how you can remember `stdClass()` from the word `AIDS` ?

Comment: not doesn't walways work as stdClass doesn't match to object so will result in the error "must be an instance of object, instance of stdClass returned"

Answer (score 236):

The standard way to create an "empty" object is:

```
$oVal = new stdClass();
```

But I **personally** prefer to use:

```
$oVal = (object)[];
```

It's shorter and I personally consider it clearer because *stdClass* could be misleading to novice programmers (i.e. "Hey, I want an object, not a class!"...).

---

**`(object)[]` is equivalent to `new stdClass()`.**

See the PHP manual ([here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php#reserved.classes.standard)):

> **stdClass**: Created by typecasting to object.

and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting):

> If an object is converted to an object, it is not modified. If a value of any other type is converted to an object, **a new instance of the stdClass built-in class is created**.

and [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) (starting with PHP 7.3.0, `var_export()` exports an object casting an array with `(object)`):

> Now exports stdClass objects as an array cast to an object ((object) array( ... )), rather than using the nonexistent method stdClass::__setState(). The practical effect is that now stdClass is exportable, and the resulting code will even work on earlier versions of PHP.

---

However remember that **empty($oVal) returns false**, as @PaulP said:

> Objects with no properties are no longer considered empty.

Regarding your example, if you write:

```
$oVal = new stdClass();
$oVal->key1->var1 = "something"; // this creates a warning with PHP < 8
                                 // and a fatal error with PHP >=8
$oVal->key1->var2 = "something else";
```

PHP < 8 creates the following Warning, implicitly creating the property `key1` (an object itself)

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value

PHP >= 8 creates the following Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "key1"

In my opinion your best option is:

```
$oVal = (object)[
  'key1' => (object)[
    'var1' => "something",
    'var2' => "something else",
  ],
];
```

Comment: Instead of fixing the problem, you're creating a new one. The problem that needs fixing is that people should know what `stdClass` does.

Comment: I wrote what `stdClass` does. I used `stdClass` on the code that answers the question. I'm sorry but I'm not creating a new problem, that was my personal opinion (as I wrote).

Comment: I'm referring to your preference of using `$oVal = (object) [];`. If you indeed do `$oVal = (object) [];`, then that's a problem.

Comment: "personal preference" != "problem"

Comment: It's not a problem if you write code alone and only need to interface with yourself.

Comment: @Pacerier, I don't understand your stubbornness. The question was 'How to define an empty object in PHP'. My answer is correct and I wrote to use "new stdClass()". The code that I provided to user 'ed209' is correct and I used "new stdClass()". In addition I added a personal opinion and I used a bold "personally" to be clear that was not the "standard" way to go. In my humble opinion a problem which deserves so many comments should be at least a wrong answer. Instead if you consider a personal opinion a problem, maybe *this* is a problem for a constructive sharing of ideas.

Comment: I really like the shorthand `(object) []`

Comment: @RahilWazir I don't know if I'd call it shorthand. It's 11 characters vs. 14, but the fact that the parentheses are separated-- I can't type them both at once like I can at the end of "stdClass()"-- means it actually might be more of a pain to type. You have to reach up onto that top row twice instead of once. It is neat, though.

Comment: `$oVal = (object)[];` How do I append data in this object?

Comment: `(object)[];` is no way a shorter or any better to `new stdClass;` . No need of 4 parenthesis, no need to press SHIFT two times and so on. btw, stdClass doesnt need `()`,and moreover you can create your shorhand overload (using `class XYZ extends stdClass`) once in your project for `new stdClass`, and then you can initiate like: `new xyz` .  **Better to accommodate the standard concepts.**

Comment: @T.Todua I consider `(object)[]` better than `new stdClass` because it allows to create objects on the fly, for example `$o = (object)['key1'=>(object)[],'key2'=>(object)[]];`. Also **it is** a standard concept, in fact, as I pointed out in my post, it is used by PHP on `var_export` function because `stdClass` is not a viable solution for that case.

Answer (score 41):

I want to point out that in PHP there is no such thing like empty object in sense:

```
$obj = new stdClass();
var_dump(empty($obj)); // bool(false)
```

but of course $obj will be empty.

On other hand empty array mean empty in both cases

```
$arr = array();
var_dump(empty($arr));
```

Quote from changelog function [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

> Objects with no properties are no longer considered empty.

Comment: I could not find that quote in the changelog for empty.

Comment: @powpow12 [It used to be there](https://web.archive.org/web/20110828212508/https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). It was changed in 5.0.0.

Answer (score 31):

### Short answer

```
$myObj = new stdClass();

// OR 

$myObj = (object) [
    "foo" => "Foo value",
    "bar" => "Bar value"
];
```

---

### Long answer

I love how easy is to create objects of anonymous type in JavaScript:

```
//JavaScript
var myObj = {
    foo: "Foo value",
    bar: "Bar value"
};
console.log(myObj.foo); //Output: Foo value
```

So I always try to write this kind of objects in PHP *like javascript does*:

```
//PHP >= 5.4
$myObj = (object) [
    "foo" => "Foo value",
    "bar" => "Bar value"
];

//PHP < 5.4
$myObj = (object) array(
    "foo" => "Foo value",
    "bar" => "Bar value"
);

echo $myObj->foo; //Output: Foo value
```

But as this is basically an array you can't do things like assign anonymous functions to a property like js does:

```
//JavaScript
var myObj = {
    foo: "Foo value",
    bar: function(greeting) {
        return greeting + " bar";
    }
};
console.log(myObj.bar("Hello")); //Output: Hello bar

//PHP >= 5.4
$myObj = (object) [
    "foo" => "Foo value",
    "bar" => function($greeting) {
        return $greeting . " bar";
    }
];
var_dump($myObj->bar("Hello")); //Throw 'undefined function' error
var_dump($myObj->bar); //Output: "object(Closure)"
```

Well, you can do it, but IMO isn't practical / clean:

```
$barFunc = $myObj->bar;
echo $barFunc("Hello"); //Output: Hello bar
```

Also, using this synthax you can find some [funny surprises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10333200/1703516), but works fine for most cases.

Answer (score 20):

php.net said it is best:

```
$new_empty_object = new stdClass();
```

Comment: Yeah, this for sure is the recommended way.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to zombat's answer if you keep forgetting `stdClass`

```
   function object(){

        return new stdClass();

    }
```

Now you can do:

```
$str='';
$array=array();
$object=object();
```

Comment: I love this technique, although most IDEs won't highlight the term "object" as a function which could be confusing to other programmers. But hey, it works for me!

Answer (score 10):

You can use `new stdClass()` (which is recommended):

```
$obj_a = new stdClass();
$obj_a->name = "John";
print_r($obj_a);

// outputs:
// stdClass Object ( [name] => John )
```

Or you can convert an empty array to an object which produces a new empty instance of the stdClass built-in class:

```
$obj_b = (object) [];
$obj_b->name = "John";
print_r($obj_b);

// outputs: 
// stdClass Object ( [name] => John )
```

Or you can convert the `null` value to an object which produces a new empty instance of the stdClass built-in class:

```
$obj_c = (object) null;
$obj_c->name = "John";
print($obj_c);

// outputs:
// stdClass Object ( [name] => John )
```

Answer (score 8):

Use a generic object and map key value pairs to it.

```
$oVal = new stdClass();
$oVal->key = $value
```

Or cast an array into an object

```
$aVal = array( 'key'=>'value' );
$oVal = (object) $aVal;
```

Answer (score 6):

to access data in a stdClass in similar fashion you do
with an asociative array just use the {$var} syntax.

```
$myObj = new stdClass;
$myObj->Prop1 = "Something";
$myObj->Prop2 = "Something else";

// then to acces it directly

echo $myObj->{'Prop1'};
echo $myObj->{'Prop2'};

// or what you may want

echo $myObj->{$myStringVar};
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try this way also.

```
<?php
     $obj = json_decode("{}"); 
     var_dump($obj);
?>
```

Output:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (0) { }
```

Answer (score 5):

As others have pointed out, you can use stdClass. However based on the question, it seems like what you really want is to be able to add properties to an object on the fly. You don't need to use stdClass for that, although you can. Really you can use any class. Just create an object instance of any class and start setting properties. I like to create my own class whose name is simply o with some basic extended functionality that I like to use in these cases and is nice for extending from other classes. Basically it is my own base object class. I also like to have a function simply named o(). Like so:

```
class o {
  // some custom shared magic, constructor, properties, or methods here
}

function o() {
  return new o();
}
```

If you don't like to have your own base object type, you can simply have o() return a new stdClass. One advantage is that o is easier to remember than stdClass and is shorter, regardless of if you use it as a class name, function name, or both. Even if you don't have any code inside your o class, it is still easier to memorize than the awkwardly capitalized and named stdClass (which may invoke the idea of a 'sexually transmitted disease class'). If you do customize the o class, you might find a use for the o() function instead of the constructor syntax. It is a normal function that returns a value, which is less limited than a constructor. For example, a function name can be passed as a string to a function that accepts a callable parameter. A function also supports chaining. So you can do something like:
$result= o($internal_value)->some_operation_or_conversion_on_this_value();

This is a great start for a base "language" to build other language layers upon with the top layer being written in full internal DSLs. This is similar to the lisp style of development, and PHP supports it way better than most people realize. I realize this is a bit of a tangent for the question, but the question touches on what I think is the base for fully utilizing the power of PHP.

EDIT/UPDATE:
I no longer recommend any of this. It makes it hard for static analysis tools and IDEs and custom AST based tools to understand, validate, help you lookup or write your code. Generally magic is bad except in some cases if you are able to get your tools to understand the magic and if it you do it in a standard enough way that even standard community tools will understand it or if your tools are so advanced and full featured that you only use your own tools. Also, I think they are deprecating the ability to add properties to random objects in an upcoming version of PHP, I think it will only work with certain ones, but I don't recommend using that feature anyways.

Comment: @Pacerier do you mean parentheseslessness? ;) http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/JavaSyntax/parentheses.html

Comment: That's a typo, it should be parenthesislessness.

Comment: @Pacerier good point http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/130219/parentheses-or-parenthesis

Answer (score 5):

If you want to create object (like in javascript) with dynamic properties, without receiving a warning of undefined property.

```
class stdClass {

public function __construct(array $arguments = array()) {
    if (!empty($arguments)) {
        foreach ($arguments as $property => $argument) {
            if(is_numeric($property)):
                $this->{$argument} = null;
            else:
                $this->{$property} = $argument;
            endif;
        }
    }
}

public function __call($method, $arguments) {
    $arguments = array_merge(array("stdObject" => $this), $arguments); // Note: method argument 0 will always referred to the main class ($this).
    if (isset($this->{$method}) && is_callable($this->{$method})) {
        return call_user_func_array($this->{$method}, $arguments);
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdObject::{$method}()");
    }
}

public function __get($name){
    if(property_exists($this, $name)):
        return $this->{$name};
    else:
        return $this->{$name} = null;
    endif;
}

public function __set($name, $value) {
    $this->{$name} = $value;
}

}

$obj1 = new stdClass(['property1','property2'=>'value']); //assign default property
echo $obj1->property1;//null
echo $obj1->property2;//value

$obj2 = new stdClass();//without properties set
echo $obj2->property1;//null
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to do this:

```
$myObj = new stdClass();
$myObj->key_1 = 'Hello';
$myObj->key_2 = 'Dolly';
```

You can use one of the following:

**PHP >=5.4**

```
$myObj = (object) [
    'key_1' => 'Hello',
    'key_3' => 'Dolly',
];
```

**PHP <5.4**

```
$myObj = (object) array(
    'key_1' => 'Hello',
    'key_3' => 'Dolly',
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here an example with the iteration:

```
<?php
$colors = (object)[];
$colors->red = "#F00";
$colors->slateblue = "#6A5ACD";
$colors->orange = "#FFA500";

foreach ($colors as $key => $value) : ?>
    <p style="background-color:<?= $value ?>">
        <?= $key ?> -> <?= $value ?>
    </p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

stdClass is the default PHP object. stdClass has no properties, methods or parent. It does not support magic methods, and implements no interfaces.

When you cast a scalar or array as Object, you get an instance of stdClass. You can use stdClass whenever you need a generic object instance.

```
<?php
// ways of creating stdClass instances
$x = new stdClass;
$y = (object) null;        // same as above
$z = (object) 'a';         // creates property 'scalar' = 'a'
$a = (object) array('property1' => 1, 'property2' => 'b');
?>
```

stdClass is NOT a base class! PHP classes do not automatically inherit from any class. All classes are standalone, unless they explicitly extend another class. PHP differs from many object-oriented languages in this respect.

```
<?php
// CTest does not derive from stdClass
class CTest {
    public $property1;
}
$t = new CTest;
var_dump($t instanceof stdClass);            // false
var_dump(is_subclass_of($t, 'stdClass'));    // false
echo get_class($t) . "\n";                   // 'CTest'
echo get_parent_class($t) . "\n";            // false (no parent)
?>
```

You cannot define a class named 'stdClass' in your code. That name is already used by the system. You can define a class named 'Object'.

You could define a class that extends stdClass, but you would get no benefit, as stdClass does nothing.

(tested on PHP 5.2.8)

Answer (score 2):

You can also get an empty object by parsing JSON:

```
$blankObject= json_decode('{}');
```

Comment: Please do not duplicate existing answers, especially if you do not provide any futher explanation

Answer (score 1):

You have this bad but usefull technic:

```
$var = json_decode(json_encode([]), FALSE);
```