# How to use Laravel response()->json() to return empty object instead of empty array

Tags: json, laravel-5

In Laravel 5.5

```
Route::get('/test2', function (){
    $data = (object) [];

    return response()->json($data);

});
```

it always returns `[]` rather than `{}`.

---

another code:

```
Route::get('/test2', function (){
    $data = (object) [];

    return json_encode($data);

});
```

it correctly returns `{}`

---

I want to use `response()->json()` helper to return **empty object** instead of **empty array**, is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define an empty object in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434368/how-to-define-an-empty-object-in-php)

Comment: @DrNio not the same problem. see my code, already defined a object data, but problem is using response() -> json() always return empty array for the data.

Comment: Hmm your first variant should be ok as well since by default it uses the `json_encode`. Unless your `ResponseFactory` does not return the default `JsonResponse`. Could you try this: `return response()->json($data, 200, [], JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);`

Answer (score 15):

This works:

```php
return response()->json(new stdClass());
```

Answer (score 6):

One more example, inspired by Hamid Mohayeji answer:

```php
return \response()->json(null);
```

No need to instantiate `stdClass` (memory allocation though).

Answer (score 5):

This works in Laravel 5.6

```
Route::get('/test2', function (){
    $data = (object) [];

    return response()->json($data, 200, [], JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

});
```

Comment: This works in Laravel 9 too, and should be the accepted answer.
Using the facade: `Response::json([], options: JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);`

Answer (score 2):

Using dingo/api modifies the answer of the empty array as @kingshark said, but you can make this work without stoping using dingo or modifying anything else than your own response.

Dingo expects the $data to be already encoded as json, so, if you do:

```
$data = ['message' => 'Lorem Ipsum', 
         'errors' => []];
return response()->json($data);
```

Will get:

```
{
    "message": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "errors": []
}
```

But if you do:

```
$data = ['message' => 'Lorem Ipsum', 
         'errors' => []];
$data = json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
return response()->json($data);
```

You will get:

```
{
    "message": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "errors": {}
}
```

Comment: I'm getting "{}" instead of {} only. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

When you return `response()->json($data)`, it returns a `JsonResponse` object which includes `$data` in `data` field. So when you receive this response, you get the data with the same format(object).

> JsonResponse json(string|array $data = [], int $status = 200, array
>   $headers = [], int $options)

When you return `json_encode($data)`, it will parse the `$data` and returns a string: `"{}"`. Only if you decode `"{}"`, it will become object again.

> string json_encode ( mixed $value [, int $options = 0 [, int $depth =
>   512 ]] )

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everyone, finally I found the problem: **`dingo/api`**.

If I use response()->json($data) in app using `dingo/api` package, there is a different response handling process. At some point, it will go through `\Dingo\Api\Http\Response::makeFromJson` method which decode the response content, then create a new response instance, which changed `{}` to `[]`.

If I removed or do not use `dingo/api` package, response()->json() can work well, at least in Laravel 5.5.

> dingo/api override, change and extend large amount of laravel built-in classes and approach in the entire request life cycle, from route to response to exception handling.

Comment: This does not work, atleast in Laravel 8. Result is still empty array, not object. Solution that works is empty stdClass like Tarasovych answered above.