# How to remove scalar property from an object?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm trying to create new object from an array of values. 
I don't know to create new `object`. 
So I added following lines.

```
$object = (object) '';
$object->vehicleId = $vehicleId;
```

But it automatically adds a new property `scalar` in the object. How to remove it?

Comment: Just do `$object = new stdClass;` or if you have an array of values, just `$object = (object)$array;`

Comment: no. `stdClass` won't work with laravel.

Comment: maybe he was already in a different namespace than `\ ` @AbraCadaver

Comment: @N69S: Well then learning PHP and namespaces would be a start ;-)

Comment: @AbraCadaver you could also be more precise and say do `new \stdClass()`

Comment: @N69S that's not necessary unless the current namespace you're working in happens to have a class named StdClass, which seems exceeding unlikely. Same reason you don't have to prefix `substr()` or `preg_match()` eg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define an empty object in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434368/how-to-define-an-empty-object-in-php)

Comment: @AbraCadaver  stdClass instantiation wont work like functions. You should try it.

Comment: @N69S: I have no idea what you are talking about https://3v4l.org/9t0e9

Comment: @AbraCadaver here https://3v4l.org/sY2sI

Comment: @N69S That is what you get if you do not define full name for your classes. https://3v4l.org/QjJoB

Answer (score 1):

As per the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting):

> If an object is converted to an object, it is not modified. If a value of any other type is converted to an object, a new instance of the stdClass built-in class is created. If the value was NULL, the new instance will be empty. An array converts to an object with properties named by keys and corresponding values. Note that in this case before PHP 7.2.0 numeric keys have been inaccessible unless iterated.

When you cast a string to an object the value of that string will be saved as an attribute. The default name is given which is `scalar`. Even an empty string is still considered to hold a value.

In PHP you have multiple ways of creating an empty object.

An example taken from https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#118679

```
<?php
$obj1 = new \stdClass; // Instantiate stdClass object
$obj2 = new class{}; // Instantiate anonymous class
$obj3 = (object)[]; // Cast empty array to object

var_dump($obj1); // object(stdClass)#1 (0) {}
var_dump($obj2); // object(class@anonymous)#2 (0) {}
var_dump($obj3); // object(stdClass)#3 (0) {}
```

Another way would be to cast a null value to an object as N69S shown:

```
$object = (object)null; // Same as (object)[]
```

And of course you can convert an associative array to an object:

```
$object = (object)['a' => 123];

// object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
//   ["a"]=>
//  int(123)
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate an object `stdClass` with `new`:

```
$object = new stdClass();
$object->vehicleId = $vehicleId;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just do it the conventional way

```php
$object = new \stdClass();
```

or with null conversion

```php
$object = (object)null;
```

and if you already have an array, you can convert it to object

```php
$object = (object)$array;
```