# Attempt to assign property on null

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to create a soap request in PHP and am new to both. I have:

```
<?php

define("PRODUCTION_KEY", "YOUR_PRODUCTION_KEY_HERE");
define("PRODUCTION_PASS", "YOUR_PRODUCTION_PASS_HERE");
define("BILLING_ACCOUNT", "YOUR_ACCOUNT_HERE");
define("REGISTERED_ACCOUNT", "YOUR_ACCOUNT_HERE");
define("USER_TOKEN", "YOUR_USER_TOKEN_HERE");

function createPWSSOAPClient(){
  $client = new SoapClient( "./wsdl/trackingservice.wsdl", 
                            array   (
                                    'trace'         =>  true,
                                    'location'  =>  "https://example.com",
                                    'uri'               =>  "http://example.com/datatypes/v1",
                                    'login'         =>  PRODUCTION_KEY,
                                    'password'  =>  PRODUCTION_PASS
                                  )
                          );
  //Define the SOAP Envelope Headers
  $headers[] = new SoapHeader ( 'http://example.com/datatypes/v1', 
                                'RequestContext', 
                                array (
                                        'Version'           =>  '1.2',
                                        'Language'          =>  'en',
                                        'GroupID'           =>  'xxx',
                                        'RequestReference'  =>  'Rating Example',
                                        'UserToken'         =>  USER_TOKEN
                                      )
                              ); 
  $client->__setSoapHeaders($headers);

  return $client;
}

$client = createPWSSOAPClient();
$request->PINS = array();
$request->PINs->PIN->Value = "1234567";
$response = $client->TrackPackagesByPin($request);
```

The request itself should look like the following:

```
/** 
  * SOAP Request Envelope (Request Made from the SOAP Client)
  * <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  * <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/datatypes/v1"><SOAP-ENV:Header><ns1:RequestContext><ns1:Version>1.0</ns1:Version><ns1:Language>en</ns1:Language><ns1:GroupID>xxx</ns1:GroupID><ns1:RequestReference>Rating Example</ns1:RequestReference></ns1:RequestContext></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:TrackByPIN><ns1:PINs><ns1:PIN><ns1:Value>1234567</ns1:Value></ns1:PIN></ns1:PINs></ns1:TrackByPIN></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
**/
```

However, when I run the above code I get:
`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property "PINS" on null`
I realize that request is null but I don't know what to set it to because I do need the `SOAP-ENV:Body` but couldn't find anything in the SOAP docs about setting a body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is related to well documented **Backward Incompatible Changes in PHP 8** (see [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php)).

Basically, PHP < 7.4 allowed you to assign properties and create an object on the fly. PHP 8 does not allow this anymore (*i.e. because the object doesn't exist, something you recognize*). Specifically:

> - A number of warnings have been converted into Error exceptions:
>
>   - Attempting to write to a property of a non-object. Previously this implicitly created an stdClass object for null, false and empty strings. ([reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php#migration80.incompatible.core.other:%7E:text=Attempting%20to%20write%20to%20a%20property%20of%20a%20non%2Dobject.%20Previously%20this%20implicitly%20created%20an%20stdClass%20object%20for%20null%2C%20false%20and%20empty%20strings))

To resolve, set the properties of an object on creation, rather than referencing new properties of something that is null and is not yet created. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29147028/12817447) for reference:

```php
$client = createPWSSOAPClient();

$request = (object)[
     'PINS' => (object)[
          'PIN' => (object)[
               'Value' => "1234567"      
           ],
     ],
 ];

$response = $client->TrackPackagesByPin($request);
```