# How do I fix the PHP Strict error "Creating default object from empty value"?

Tags: php

I have the following PHP5 code:

```
$request = NULL;
$request->{"header"}->{"sessionid"}        =  $_SESSION['testSession'];
$request->{"header"}->{"type"}             =  "request";
```

Lines 2 and 3 are producing the following error:

> PHP Strict standards:  Creating default object from empty value

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Just curious, where did you see this style before?
$request->{"header"}->{"sessionid"}

Comment: I saw it while framing JSON Requests.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Null isn't an object, so you can't assign values to it. From what you are doing it looks like you need an [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). If you are dead set on using objects, you could use the [stdClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php)

```
//using arrays
$request = array();
$request["header"]["sessionid"]        =  $_SESSION['testSession'];
$request["header"]["type"]             =  "request";

//using stdClass
$request = new stdClass();
$request->header = new stdClass();
$request->header->sessionid        =  $_SESSION['testSession'];
$request->header->type             =  "request";
```

I would recommend using arrays, as it is a neater syntax with (probably) the same underlying implementation.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with stdClass().. However, the array() style works just fine...

Thank you

Answer (score 13):

Get rid of $request = NULL and replace with:

```
$request = new stdClass;
$request->header = new stdClass;
```

You are trying to write to NULL instead of an actual object.

Answer (score 4):

To suppress the error:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

To fix the error:

```
$request = new stdClass();
```

hth

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to set attributes on a null value? Use an associative array instead.