# Strict standards: Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php

I have the following code.

```
        public function get_users_theme($uid)
            {
                    $r = $this->db2->query('SELECT * FROM users_theme WHERE user_id="'.$uid.'" LIMIT 1', FALSE);
                    if ($this->db2->num_rows($r) > 0) {
                            $o->user_theme = new stdClass();
                            $ut = $this->db2->fetch_object($r);
                            foreach($ut as $l=>$s) {
                                    $o->user_theme->$l  = stripslashes($s);
            }
                            return $o->user_theme;
                    } else {
                            return FALSE;
                    }
            }
```

It appears that line 5 are producing the following error:

> Strict standards: Creating default object from empty value

How Can I Fix That ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Strict standards: Creating default object from empty value - How to Fix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949966/php-strict-standards-creating-default-object-from-empty-value-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$o` has not been declared when you start to use it as an object, so just make it an stdClass object beforehand:

```
$o = new stdClass();
$o->user_theme = new stdClass();
```

Or, even better, replace `$o->user_theme` everywhere in that function with `$user_theme` - since your code doesn't seem to require a special object a normal variable will be sufficient.