# after upgrading my php5.4 Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php

I have a problem related to php version 5.4. I am using php5.4. Before it was 5.2.

Now I have problem after upgrading. Now my site has lots of warnings

> Creating default object from empty value

I am trying to solve this by checking other posts, but no success.

Warnings are at this line

```
$searchresult[$pluginname][$i]->title = $value->title;
```

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949966/php-strict-standards-creating-default-object-from-empty-value-how-to-fix and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243749/php5-creating-default-object-from-empty-value

Comment: You cant do what your doing, unless you initialize `$searchresult[$pluginname][$i]` as a stdClass() first or create a special __set() method in the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the stupid way to approach this problem, but you get that warning off you back by setting `error_reporting` to `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT`.

It's specially helpful if you're going to do the wrong thing any way and not rewrite the code as @theredled suggests above.

Comment: Thanks Rob...Currently i m using it :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with older versions of PHP, you could do :

```
$a = null;
$a->somevar = 3;`
```

Because $a was automaticly turned into stdClass type.

With PHP 5.4 you can't do that : you have to instanciate $a manually.

```
$a = new stdClass(); 
$a->somevar = 3;`
```

Or better, use arrays if you can :

```
$a = array('somevar' => 3);
```

Comment: thanks now warnings removed.. i use $searchresult[$pluginname][$i]=new stdClass();.... also  Lawrence Cherone suggests... thanks everybody for your kind help.. Regards