# To JSON and json_decode in PHP and JavaScript

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to pass a JavaScript object to a PHP script through `jquery.ajax()`, basically:

```
var bigArray = new Object();
//Dode
//Start loop
bigArray[x] = {name: exname, id: exID, order:e, set: setBox, inc: incBox, example: exampleBox, day: i};
```

So it's pretty much an array of these objects.

```
    var anotherTest = $.toJSON(bigArray);
    var ajxFile = "routineajax.php";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        url: ajxFile,
        data: anotherTest,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
            alert('Load was performed.');
        }
    });
});
```

The PHP side script

```
 print_r($_POST);
 $params = json_decode($_POST);
 print_r($params)
```

The Ajax call is going through, and I can see in [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29), but `print_r($_POST)` is returning an empty array. While if I change it to `$_GET` in both the `$.ajax` function and PHP script it works. My main problem is I'm getting this error message:

> Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

How do I fix this problem?

---

After adding this snippet to the PHP file

```
  $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
  var_dump($data);
  var_dump(json_decode($data));
```

I'm getting this output

```
string'{"0"{"name":"Decline`Abs","id":"54","order":0,"set":"","inc":"","example":"","day":1}}' (length=87)`
  object(stdClass)[2]
      public '0' =>
        object(stdClass)[4]
          public 'name' => string 'Decline Abs' (length=11)
          public 'id' => string '54' (length=2)
          public 'order' => int 0
          public 'set' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'inc' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'example' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'day' => int 1
```

So at least it's going through, I'm not sure how to access it though, a step in the right direction!

Comment: Can you edit your question with the results of doing print_r($_GET). I see you have it below, but it's unclear to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that normally POST data is sent encoded as `key=value&key2=value2`, and you're sending it as JSON. Try accessing the raw post data as follows:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
var_dump($data);
var_dump(json_decode($data));
```

and see if that works. If not, please post in your question what it returns, if anything.

---

**Based on the comment below and additions to the OP.**

Did the `var_dump` of `$data` copy-paste correctly? The reason I ask is that this: `string'{"0"{"name"` does not look right to me. That isn't valid JSON or a properly encoded POST string. It might be that some of the characters got encoded when you copied and pasted.

Either way, you're now getting the result you need. The `stdClass` is just a blank container that it puts the data into, which you can access using the normal object syntax. In this case, you'd have to do `$data->{0}->name` I think, because of that `0`. If you do `$data = json_decode($data, true)` it will be an associative array, and you can access the POST'ed data as `$data[0]['name']`.

If you want to keep exploring this, it might be helpful to show the results of doing `window.console.dir(data)` right before you do the ajax request, and make sure when you `var_dump(data)`, you view the source of the page to copy and paste. `window.console.dir(data)` will show `data`'s properties in the Firebug window (you are using Firebug, right?). It also works in Chrome's debugger, and maybe others as well. Like I said though, it looks like you're probably getting what you need already, so investigating isn't necessary.

Comment: I added the output in the OP. It seems to be moving in the right direction now. Can you explain whats going on though?

Comment: SO question about stdclass, in case you're unfamiliar with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it clear enough? `json_decode()` expects parameter one to be string, not array. But `$_POST` and `$_GET` are always arrays. You can pass a member of this array to `json_decode()`.

To see an array's contents, use this snippet:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_GET);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: I think the problem is with toJSON since this is the $_GET output I'm getting:
Array ( [{"0":{"name":"Bent_Over_Rows","id":"27","order":0,"set":"","inc":"","example":"","day":1}}] => ) 

Instead of 0 => elements. But at least the array error is gone...

Answer (score 0):

Turn `processData` to true. I don't believe your JSON is being passed through correctly. Also note that it won't come through as a json, but rather the key value pairs of your JSON will be the contents of `$_POST` when you get to it.

Also, are the values of your bigArray easily convertable to string? If you're passing in DOM elements or something, you're going to have issues.

Comment: Turned on processData, and still the PHP isn't picking up the $_POST. I know it's going through because I see it in firebug here:
Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
{"0":{"name":"Decline Abs... 

Only $_GET has been going through..

Comment: Try not converting bigArray to a JSON at all. jQuery.ajax() expects an object for the data parameter anyway: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Sending bigArray through POST gives me this
Array
(
    [0] => [object Object]
    [1] => [object Object]
)
So seems like it didnt pass the object through.