# How to create a dynamic object in a loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, object

Basically I want to create one large object of many object in JavaScript. Something like:

```
var objects = {}
for (x)
objects.x = {name: etc}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is very confusing.  Answer this: What are you looping over and what is your intended result.  State your input and your desired output.

Comment: It might be just me, but I don't get it...

Comment: This question relates to my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375143/problem-with-tojson-and-json-decode-in-php-and-js

I tried passing it as an array of objects but its somehow not working, so I'm trying this method. Something like:
ManyObjects: { Object1 : {name:etc, x:etc},
Object2 : {name:etc, x:etc}}

Answer (score 96, accepted):

```
var objects = {};

for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
  objects[x] = {name: etc};
}
```

Answer (score 16):

### An actual implementation

Populate a container object with 100 other objects.

```
<script>
var container = { }; // main object

// add 100 sub-object values
for(i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
 container['prop'+i ]  /*property name or key of choice*/
         = { 'a':'something', 
             'b':'somethingelse', 
             'c': 2 * i
           }; 
}
```

TEST THE Results - iterate and display objects...

```
for(var p in container) {
 var innerObj = container[p];
 document.write('<div>container.' + p + ':' + innerObj + '</div>');
 // write out properties of inner object
 document.write('<div> .a: ' + innerObj['a'] + '</div>');
 document.write('<div> .b: ' + innerObj['b'] + '</div>');
 document.write('<div> .c: ' + innerObj['c'] + '</div>');
}
</script>
```

Output is like

```
container.prop0:[object Object]
.a: something
.b: somethingelse
.c: 0
container.prop1:[object Object]
.a: something
.b: somethingelse
.c: 2
container.prop2:[object Object]
.a: something
.b: somethingelse
.c: 4
```

etc...

Answer (score 9):

Using `object[propertyname]` is the same as using `object.propertyname` and hence we can dynamically create object keys with `object[propertyname]` format
for eg:

```js
var fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana","Grapes"];
var colors = ["red", "Orange", "yellow","blue"];
var newObj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
  newObj[fruits[i]] = colors[i];
}
console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
var objects = new Array();
var howmany = 10;

for (var i = 0; i < howmany; i++)
{
    objects[i] = new Object();

}
```

Comment: You have a leaking global `i` variable. Don't forget to use `var`.

Comment: Do not use **new Array()**  and **new Object()** as it is not efficient performance wise. Instead use the literals.

Answer (score 1):

```js
//On Nested Obj like that
var playersCount = {
    "Players" : {}
}

var exempleCount = 5;

for(i=0; i <= exempleCount;i++){
    var BadID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
  
        playersCount.Players["Player_"+i] = {
            "id":BadID, 
            "xPos":0, 
            "yPos":0, 
            "zPos":0
        };
    }
  console.log(playersCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reusable approach for creation dynamic object

```js
const text = ["Cherries", "Strawberry", "Banana"];
const emoji = ["", "", ""];

const createDynamicObj = (keys, values) => {
  if(!keys || !values) return
  let newObj = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    newObj[keys[i]] = values[i];
  }
  return newObj
}


console.log(
  createDynamicObj(emoji, text)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following simple function:

```js
function mapObject(array, cb, initial = {}) {
    const obj = initial;

    array.forEach((item, index) => cb(obj, item, index));

    return obj;
}

// js example
console.log('new object:', mapObject(['a', 'b', 'c'], (obj, key, i) => obj[key] = i * 2));
```

Or better with **typescript version**:

```
function mapObject<O extends object, T>(array: T[], cb: (obj: O, item: T, index: number) => void, initial = {} as O): O {
    const obj = initial;

    array.forEach((item, index) => cb(obj, item, index));

    return obj;
}

// ts example
console.log('new object:', mapObject<{ total: number }, number>([1, 2, 3], (obj, num) => {
    obj.total += num;
}, { total: 0 }));
```

> If you have error for eslint rule `no-param-reassign` - just put to rules: `'no-param-reassign': ['error', { props: false }]`