# Need help getting sum of xml elements and more

Tags: php, html, xml

So I am creating a software for a store where each item has a qr code that has `<id>0000</ id>`, `<name>NameHere</name>`, and `<price>5</price>` in the `xml` element. I need to make a PHP page that allows you to type in the id number and it will fill in the name and price values into a table. Then you have to be able to click the "total" button and it adds up all the price values.

I am new to PHP so I really need some help! I have tried different things, but I can't get exactly what I described!

My xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<item><id>0001</id><name>Banana</name><price>5</price></item>
```

Comment: Please add what you have tried. If seems that you have done your homework. If you provide some Code we meight can help you.

Comment: @rekire I updated it!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use AJAX on top of PHP, as the javascript will process the client side, and the PHP will process the server side. I would suggest using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) for your [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) calls.

#### Your workflow would look like this if you were to use PHP and jQuery:

1. User types ID in a `<input>` box in the HTML page
2. User clicks some sort of button, to run the jQuery AJAX function
3. AJAX function takes the ID in the box through `$("input").val()`, `POSTS` it to the PHP page
4. PHP processes the ID, matches it in the database (or XML file), and `json_encode()`'s the resulting rows, to look something like this:

   `{
   "ID": [
       {
           "name": "Banana",
           "price": "5"
       }
   ]
   }`
5. Your PHP code `echo()`'s the `JSON` string
6. `onSuccess()`, your jQuery parses the JSON through `paseJSON()`
7. You can then access your `name` and `price` through something like `data["ID"][0]` and `data["ID")[1]`
8. Set the `.val()` of the other `<input>` elements to that of `data["ID"][0]` and `data["ID"][1]`

#### Pure PHP:

1. Output HTML via PHP that includes the same form elements as above
2. When you press submit, `POST` the values of the `ID` element to that same PHP file
3. Have your PHP file recognize that the ID is being `POST`ed to it
4. Match the ID with the ID in your XML file, and retrieve the corresponding rows
5. Set the text of the other `input` elements to that of the variables retrieved from step 4

Using pure PHP might be a pain, however, if you're going to eventually add the variables, as you'll need a way to retain the previous variables. If you use AJAX, you simply `append()` the new items to the same HTML page, then create a separate function to add the prices.

You could also potentially find a solution without using PHP, and having a javascript library parse the XML file for you.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand... could you provide me with some example code? Thanks!

Comment: No, I won't write it for you. What I outlined is all very straightforward, at least in my mind it is. What are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: Like I said before... I'm VERY new to PHP. I usually learn by reading the actual code. I've never used JSON before, so I don't get what you mean at all! That's why I think an example would help! I'm a visual learner!

Comment: Then google how to use JSON strings in PHP/jQuery: **1.** http://www.packtpub.com/article/working-json-php-jquery **2.** http://www.electrictoolbox.com/json-data-jquery-php-mysql/ **3.** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375143/to-json-and-json-decode-in-php-and-javascript **4.** Google `jQuery PHP JSON`

Comment: Thanks! You've been very helpful! Are you sure there's no way to do this in just plain PHP though?

Comment: I mean, I suppose you could, but it wouldn't make much sense. If you did it in pure PHP, the user would have to enter in the ID, press a submit button, and the entire page would have to reload. With AJAX, you don't need to reload the page at all, and it provides a much better UX for clients. Also, if my answer has helped you/answered your question, don't forget to up vote and mark it as accepted, if you feel it is warranted.

Comment: Before I up vote anything, I'd like to see if you can explain how to do it in plain PHP.

Comment: +1 very good outline for a beginner without just giving TEH CODEZ