# What to name this class?

Tags: php, oop

(This is not an interface: I simply omitted the method bodies)

```
class _ {
    protected $_data = array();

    function __construct($data);

    function set($name, $value);

    function get($name);

    function __set($name, $value);
    function __get($name); //aliases for their respective non-magic methods.

    # and some other generic methods
}
```

Essentially it's a class that provides a magical object-oriented reusable access layer to some data. I've considered DataLayer, DataObject and some others; I'd like to hear some suggestions from someone who's more terminologically savvy.

Comment: That's the most generic class I've ever seen.

Comment: @Chris Kloberdanz: Is that your suggestion?

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm a stickler for DRY :p

Comment: @webbiedave StdClass is a built-in generic class in PHP, which does exactly what the class in question is trying to do.  Just use it: `$x = new StdClass();  $x->something = 'what';`

Comment: @meager stdClass will pollute the object namespace and will make it impossible to iterate over the data, as it will be mixed in with "non-data" variables.

Comment: @meagar: I was joking around asking if "It's almost like StdClass" was the suggestion.

Comment: @meager stdClass doesn't allow for intercepting property access. You can load or transform object properties on demand when you use the magic getters/setters. Many of the classes I write use this exact methodology, down to `$this->data`.

Comment: what about stating its responsibilities, collaborations, use cases... You cannot look at few lines of code and efficiently name a class, you have to know everything about it to know its purpose and name it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a class like that in Magento. Well, it's got a lot more stuff in it, but the philosophy is the same: add some magic method goodness to the rest of your classes via inheritance. They named it Varien_Object, Varien being the name of the company.

I've also got something like this in a custom framework I've helped build. It's just called Base.

I guess what I'm trying to say is... no matter what you call it, it wont help people understand what it does until they go through the code. Don't worry about it too much, by the time you're done it'll be buried so deep in your app that the only people that find it will be the kind that can grok what it does fairly quickly anyway

Answer (score 6):

How about `Dave` ;)

Seriously though, what about `DataAccess`

Comment: Tell people it's an acronym for Data Access Value Enumerator. They just might believe it!

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing how the class is used and what data it's meant to wrap, it's hard to name it.  "Wraps some data in magic OOP" is so generic that a meaningful class name is difficult.

If it's for sitting between the controller and the database, you could call it [ActiveRecord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern).

If it really is just for providing some OOP syntactic sugar to an `array()`, you could simply use the built-in [StdClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php).

Failing that, given that the only purpose of the class seems to be to wrap an array, I'd be tempted to call it `ArrayWrapper`.

Answer (score 1):

You could call it `AccessLayer`.

Answer (score 1):

It really resembles KeyPairValue and if you with to make it more specialized in defining how Get would find its entries say using a Hash() function, then it's a Hashtable.

- class KeyPairValue
- class Hashtable

Now the question is why? Most SDKs would offer such data structures?

Try to use existing structures and not re-invent them.