# How to find an element in a structured array

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

The code below returns an array of images that are "attached" to posts...

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => 0
); 
$excludeImages = get_posts($args);
```

//var_dump

```
var_dump ($excludeImages)
```

//yields (a snippet of the first item of 5 in the array)

```
array(5){[0]=&gt; object(stdClass)#194 (24) 
        {["ID"]=&gt; int(46) 
         ["guid"]=&gt; string(59) "http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/avatar.png"}
```

**The Question:**
How can I extract the image filename (in this case, avatar.png) from any given array item where the pattern is always ["guid"]=> string(int) "path-to-image"?

Comment: I am not really familiar with var_dump notation. Is that saying the 0th element of the array is an object with ID and guid attributes? Did you omit the other 4 elements?

Comment: @Scott B: as simple as `$excludeImages[0]->guid` ?

Comment: @erisco:  var_dump returns the entire contents of $excludeImages. There are 5 items in the array. I've just included the contents of the first item for simplicity/readability.

Comment: @ajreal: yes, that yields the string. I just need the filename (avatar.png) and for each item in the array. Ultimately, I need to populate a 2nd array with all the filenames [avatar.png, somefile.jpg, anothefile.gif, etc...]

Comment: As both answers suggest, use basename().

Comment: @Scott B: as suggested by @jon_darkstar, basename, to safe guard, always `urlencode` query string appended after filename, otherwise, `basename("http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/avatar.png?q=/this_is_not_what_i_want/this_should_not_show")` will return `this_should_not_show` instead `avatar.png`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use basename

```
$fileName = basename($excludeImages[0]->guid);
```

EDIT: As commenter above mentioned, i think you might need arrow notation instead of indexing for "guid" as in $excludeImages[0]["guid"].  I didn't notice initially that it is an object.  It seems you have an array of objects, not a structured/nested array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Answer (score 0):

stdClass is basically the default class for PHP (not the base!). It does not have any method or attribute, it's an empty class. It is used as a container. You can create such a class by casting an array to an object, for example.

Your var_dump means that the first element of your array is an stdClass object having a ID and guid attributes. Therefore, this code would retrieve the full guid :

```
$path = $excludeImages[0]->guid;
```

If you only want to retrieve the filename, you can use basename() :

```
echo basename($path); // avatar.png
```

You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php) for more information about stdClass.