# class defined as static member of another class

Tags: php, class, member

I do this type of thing in Java all the time, and I'm trying to figure out if it's possible in PHP.  This is what I would expect the syntax to look like if it was possible, but I'm wondering if there's some special way to do it (if it's possible, that is).

```
class Foo {
   public static class FooBarException extends Exception {
   }
   public static class BarBazException extends Exception {
   }

   public function DoSomething() {
      try {
          // Calls to other class methods that can
          // throw FooBarException and BarBazException
      } catch (self::FooBarException $e) {
          // Stuff..
      }
   }
}

$bang = new Foo();
try {
   $bang->DoSomething();
} catch (Foo::BarBazException $e) {
   // Stuff..
}
```

Comment: As an aside, I forgot if there's an actual name for doing this, in any language.  I thought it was "subclass", but that would be used as "FooBarException is a subclass of Exception"...

Comment: Aside for your aside, I think you are looking for 'inner class', and here is a link to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351782/how-do-i-use-inner-classes-in-php  Short answer is 'No'

Comment: It's also called "nested classes".

Comment: @watcher and linepogl - thanks, that would be why I couldn't find duplicates.  "Member class" kept getting treated as "class members" in searches...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can not. However, introduced in PHP 5.3 are [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php). With namespaces you could similarly do:

```
<?php
namespace MyNamespace
{
    use Exception;

    class FooBarException
        extends Exception
    {
    }

    class FooBazException
        extends Exception
    {
    }

    class Foo
    {
        public function doSomething()
        {
            throw new FooBarException;
        }
    }
}

namespace AnotherNamespace
{
    $bang = new \MyNamespace\Foo;
    try {
        $bang->doSomething();
    } catch(\MyNamespace\FooBarException $up) {
        throw $up; // :)
    }
}
```

Comment: Disappointing, but +1 and accept because I didn't even know about namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible.

You can use namespaces for a similar effect, however.

Answer (score 1):

You cann't do it in PHP, but in php 5.3 you can use namespaces for similar functionality

http://php.net/namespace