# Error "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Tags: php, json

I get a strange error using `json_decode()`. It decodes the data correctly (I saw it using `print_r`), but when I try to access to information inside the array I get:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in
C:\Users\Dail\software\abs.php on line 108
```

I only tried to do: `$result['context']` where `$result` has the data returned by `json_decode()`

How can I read values inside this array?

Comment: $result = json_decode('the string', true); Adding the true returns the result as an array and not an stdClass.

Comment: Wow, just made such a big facepalm. xD 
Already used the function so often, and still stumble doing that error. :D

Answer (score 1065):

Use the second parameter of [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to make it return an array:

```
$result = json_decode($data, true);
```

Answer (score 278):

The function [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) returns an object by default.

You can access the data like this:

```
var_dump($result->context);
```

If you have identifiers like `from-date` (the hyphen would cause a PHP error when using the above method) you have to write:

```
var_dump($result->{'from-date'});
```

If you want an array you can do something like this:

```
$result = json_decode($json, true);
```

Or cast the object to an array:

```
$result = (array) json_decode($json);
```

Comment: took me a while to find this when trying to find a way to refer to the _destroy value in php that's set by knockoutjs, so +1

Comment: This answer is much more qualified than first (most rated) answer!

Answer (score 206):

You must access it using **`->`** since it’s an object.

Change your code from:

```
$result['context'];
```

To:

```
$result->context;
```

Comment: The problem I have is trying to use the property in a conditional `if ($result->context = $var)`  This causes the property to be set to the var and returns true, no matter.

Comment: @STWilson you should be using a double equals `==`, in your current state you are assigning `$var` value to `$result->context` by using a single equal `=`. And the `if statement` will read it as if it is empty or not, and if the `$var` has value then that means it is not empty and will always return true.

Comment: Why does this page seem to indicate that both syntaxes are allowed: https://www.php.net/manual/en/sdo.sample.getset.php

Comment: @kojow7 If you are referring to this `$company->departments[0]->name` it is because it is directly accessing the object using an array index. The structure of the data is that, objects are stored in array.

Comment: @JiNexus I mean examples #1 and #2 on that page. Example #1 says you can use: `$company->name = 'Acme';` and Example #2 says you can use: `$company['name'] = 'UltraCorp';`

Comment: @kojow7 you can use them in assignment but go back to the main question of this thread he is asking how to access it. So depending of the data type that's how you access both array and object.

Comment: @JNexus If you look at example #2 on the page it shows examples of accessing it on the left hand and right hand side of the assignment operator. Therefore, it is showing that it can be both used in assignment and retrieving data from it.

Answer (score 116):

Use `true` as the second parameter to `json_decode`. This will decode the JSON content into an associative array instead of `stdObject` instances:

```
$my_array = json_decode($my_json, true);
```

See [the documentation](http://php.net/json_decode) for more details.

Comment: It works flawlessly, thank you :)

Answer (score 100):

I have the same problem today and solved like this:

If you call `json_decode($somestring)`, you will get an Object and you need to access like `$object->key`, but if you call `json_decode($somestring, true)` you will get a dictionary and can access like `$array['key']`.

Comment: This saved me sooo much time! I was not putting in the true parameter, and trying to access it as an array

Comment: Life saver!  Especially with `echo json_decode('{"Contains Space":999}', true)['Contains Space'] . "\n";`

Answer (score 73):

It's not an array; it's an object of type stdClass.

You can access it like this:

```
echo $oResult->context;
```

More information is in *[What is stdClass in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php)*.

Answer (score 31):

As the **Php Manual** say,

> print_r — Prints human-readable information about a variable

When we use `json_decode();`, we get an object of type stdClass as return type.
The arguments, which are to be passed inside of `print_r()` should either be an array or a string. Hence, we cannot pass an object inside of `print_r()`. I found 2 ways to deal with this.

1. **Cast the object to array.**
   This can be achieved as follows.

   ```
   $a = (array)$object;
   ```
2. **By accessing the key of the Object**
   As mentioned earlier, when you use `json_decode();` function, it returns an Object of stdClass. you can access the elements of the object with the help of `->` Operator.

   ```
   $value = $object->key;
   ```

One, can also use multiple keys to extract the sub elements incase if the object has nested arrays.

```
$value = $object->key1->key2->key3...;
```

Their are other options to `print_r()` as well, like `var_dump();` and `var_export();`

**P.S** : Also, If you set the second parameter of the `json_decode();` to `true`, it will automatically convert the object to an `array();` 
**Here are some references:** 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php

Answer (score 28):

Try something like this one!

Instead of getting the context like (this works for getting array index's),

```
$result['context']
```

try (this work for getting objects):

```
$result->context
```

Another example is (if `$result` has multiple data values):

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 15
            [name] => 1 Pc Meal
            [context] => 5
            [restaurant_id] => 2
            [items] =>
            [details] => 1 Thigh (or 2 Drums) along with Taters
            [nutrition_fact] => {"":""}
            [servings] => menu
            [availability] => 1
            [has_discount] => {"menu":0}
            [price] => {"menu":"8.03"}
            [discounted_price] => {"menu":""}
            [thumbnail] => YPenWSkFZm2BrJT4637o.jpg
            [slug] => 1-pc-meal
            [created_at] => 1612290600
            [updated_at] => 1612463400
        )

)
```

Then try this:

```
foreach($result as $results)
{
    $results->context;
}
```

Answer (score 25):

To get an array as result from a json string you should set second param as boolean true.

```
$result = json_decode($json_string, true);
$context = $result['context'];
```

Otherwise $result will be an std object. but you can access values as object.

```
  $result = json_decode($json_string);
 $context = $result->context;
```

Answer (score 20):

Sometimes when working with API you simply want to keep an object an object. To access the object that has nested objects you could do the following:

We will assume when you print_r the object you might see this:

```
print_r($response);

stdClass object
(
    [status] => success
    [message] => Some message from the data
    [0] => stdClass object
        (
            [first] => Robert
            [last] => Saylor
            [title] => Symfony Developer
        )
    [1] => stdClass object
        (
            [country] => USA
        )
)
```

To access the first part of the object:

```
print $response->{'status'};
```

And that would output "success"

Now let's key the other parts:

```
$first = $response->{0}->{'first'};
print "First name: {$first}<br>";
```

The expected output would be "Robert" with a line break.

You can also re-assign part of the object to another object.

```
$contact = $response->{0};
print "First Name: " . $contact->{'first'} . "<br>";
```

The expected output would be "Robert" with a line break.

To access the next key "1" the process is the same.

```
print "Country: " . $response->{1}->{'country'} . "<br>";
```

The expected output would be "USA"

Hopefully this will help you understand objects and why we want to keep an object an object. You should not need to convert an object to an array to access its properties.

Answer (score 11):

You can convert the *stdClass* object to an array like:

```
$array = (array)$stdClass;
```

[stdClsss to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396033/stdclass-to-array)

Answer (score 8):

When you try to access it as `$result['context']`, you treating it as an array, the error it's telling you that you are actually dealing with an object, then you should access it as `$result->context`

Answer (score 4):

Here is the function signature:

```
mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )
```

When a parameter is false, which is the default, it will return an appropriate PHP type. You fetch the value of that type using object.method paradigm.

When a parameter is true, it will return associative arrays.

It will return NULL on error.

If you want to fetch a value through an array, set *assoc* to true.

Comment: Is it a particular parameter? The first one?

Answer (score 2):

I got this error out of the blue because my facebook login suddently stopped working (I had also changed hosts) and throwed this error. The fix is really easy

The issue was in this code

```
  $response = (new FacebookRequest(
    FacebookSession::newAppSession($this->appId, $this->appSecret),
    'GET',
    '/oauth/access_token',
    $params
  ))->execute()->getResponse(true);

  if (isset($response['access_token'])) {       <---- this line gave error
    return new FacebookSession($response['access_token']);
  }
```

Basically isset() function expect an array but instead it find an object. The simple solution is to convert PHP object to array using **(array)** quantifier. The following is the fixed code.

```
  $response = (array) (new FacebookRequest(
    FacebookSession::newAppSession($this->appId, $this->appSecret),
    'GET',
    '/oauth/access_token',
    $params
  ))->execute()->getResponse(true);
```

**Note the use off array() quantifier in first line.**

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the brackets, use the object operator. For example, my array based on a database object is created like this in a class called *DB*:

```
class DB {

    private static $_instance = null;

    private $_pdo,
            $_query,
            $_error = false,
            $_results,
            $_count = 0;

    private function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            $this->_error = true;
            $newsMessage = 'Sorry.  Database is off line';
            $pagetitle = 'Teknikal Tim - Database Error';
            $pagedescription = 'Teknikal Tim Database Error page';
            include_once 'dbdown.html.php';
            exit;
        }
        $headerinc = 'header.html.php';
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new DB();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
        $this->_error = false;
        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            $x = 1;
            if(count($params)) {
                foreach($params as $param) {
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                    $x++;
                }
            }
        }

        if($this->_query->execute()) {

            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        }
        else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
        if(count($where) === 3) {
            $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

            $field    = $where[0];
            $operator = $where[1];
            $value    = $where[2];

            if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
                $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} = ?";

                if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
                    return $this;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function get($table, $where) {
        return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);

    public function results() {
        return $this->_results;
    }

    public function first() {
        return $this->_results[0];
    }

    public function count() {
        return $this->_count;
    }

}
```

To access the information, I use this code on the controller script:

```
<?php
    $pagetitle = 'Teknikal Tim - Service Call Reservation';
    $pagedescription = 'Teknikal Tim Sevice Call Reservation Page';
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/core/init.php';
    $newsMessage = 'temp message';

    $servicecallsdb = DB::getInstance()->get('tt_service_calls', array('UserID', '=', '$_SESSION['UserID']));

    if(!$servicecallsdb) {
        //$servicecalls[] = array('ID'=>'', 'ServiceCallDescription'=>'No Service Calls');
    } else {
        $servicecalls = $servicecallsdb->results();
    }
    include 'servicecalls.html.php';
?>
```

Then to display the information. I check to see if servicecalls has been set and has a count greater than 0. Remember it's not an array I am referencing, so I access the records with the object operator "->" like this:

```html
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/header.html.php';?>

<!-- Main content -->
<div id="mainholder"> <!-- div so that page footer can have a minimum
                           height from the header -->
<h1><?php if(isset($pagetitle)) htmlout($pagetitle);?></h1>
<br>
<br>
<article>
    <h2></h2>
</article>

<?php
    if (isset($servicecalls)) {
        if (count ($servicecalls) > 0) {
             foreach ($servicecalls as $servicecall) {
                echo '<a href="/servicecalls/?servicecall=' .
                     $servicecall->ID . '">' .
                     $servicecall->ServiceCallDescription .'</a>';
            }
        }
        else
            echo 'No service Calls';
    }
?>

<a href="/servicecalls/?new=true">Raise New Service Call</a>
</div> <!-- Main content end -->

<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/footer.html.php'; ?>
```

Comment: What a long answer to a simple question.

Comment: The code is likely syntactically incorrect in the line with "DB::getInstance" (messed up in revision 2). This is also indicated by the weird syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

Change it for

```
$results->fetch_array()
```

Comment: Do you mean `mysqli_result::fetch_array`? That seems irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely when it tries to access the data with the generic bracket array accessor and not an object operator. Always ensure the variable type is before accessing the data.

While decoding the JSON, the response will be generated as `stdObject` instances

Rather than calling `$result['context'];`, access it by `$result->context;`

If it needs to call as an array itself, decode the JSON by passing the second parameter as `true` like

```php
json_decode($jsonData, true);
```