# stdClass to array?

Tags: php

i have:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [one] => aaa
            [two] => sss
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [one] => ddd
            [two] => fff
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [one] => ggg
            [two] => hhh
        )
}
```

and i **must** get this with keys, for example:

```
$var = $stdClass[0];
```

but i have error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Is possible parse this stdClass to array and use this with keys?

Comment: Why is it a `stdClass` to begin with, can't you create it as array?

Comment: Sure just do: **$arrayRepresentation = (array) $someStdClass;**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert stdClass object to array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495068/convert-stdclass-object-to-array-in-php)

Answer (score 69):

Cast it to an array:

```
$array = (array)$stdClass;
```

Comment: Where does that data come from to begin with?

Comment: i use json and json_decode function. I add for this function parameter true, but still i have empty array

Comment: `$array = json_decode($jsonData, true);` does not work? Please show a full example, including what the JSON data looks like.

Comment: if i use true then i have empty array. If i use yout solution this working only for current array - children array still are stdClass

Comment: Yes, the children will still be `stdClass` objects, you'll have to cast them as well.

Answer (score 36):

If you're using `json_decode` to convert that JSON string into an object, you can use the second parameter `json_decode($string, true)` and that will convert the object to an associative array.

If not, what everybody else has said and just type cast it

`$array = (array) $stdClass;`

Comment: You should have no problem using `json_decode` is you do: `$array = json_decode($string, true);` Then using `print_r` will give the associative array with the keys.

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is probably solved since asking, but for reference, quick uncle-google answer:

```
function objectToArray($d) {
  if(is_object($d)) {
    $d = get_object_vars($d);
  }
  if(is_array($d)) {
    return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $d); // recursive
  } else {
    return $d;
  }
}
```

Full article [here](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/php-tip-convert-stdclass-object-to-multidimensional-array-and-convert-multidimensional-array-to-stdclass-object/). Note I'm not associated with the original author in any way.

Answer (score 7):

Cast it

```
$array = (array) $stdObject;
```

Comment: if now user $array[0] then i have empty array

Comment: this working only for current array. Childrens array still are stdObject

Comment: @LucciFangorci You didn't mentioned, that you want the whole tree. For now I don't even see a reason, why: `echo $array[0]->two`.

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can typecast, `$var = (array) $obj;`, but I would suggest [`ArrayAccess`](http://us.php.net/arrayaccess) to your class.

By using `ArrayAccess`, you can then treat your objects and data as if it was an array, or natively as an object.

Answer (score 3):

Cast it into an array. Currently it is not readable to PHP as an array.

```
$array = (array)$stdClass;
```

Comment: $array[0][one] will return aaa

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, just type cast it:

```
$arr = (array)$obj;
$var = $arr[0];
```

But read the caveats [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting).

Comment: since you've got objects inside of objects, you'll need to cast the containing object to an array and iterate it. While iterating through it, access the property you want `$var->one`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an nested array you can used `json_encode` and `json_decode` to convert the whole object to an array:

```
$result = json_decode(json_encode($source), JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY);
```

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me,
The decoding and encoding makes for a regular array

`$array = json_decode(json_encode($object), True);`

Answer (score 0):

```
function load_something () : \stdClass {

    $result = new \stdClass();

    $result->varA   = 'this is the value of varA';
    $result->varB   = 'this is the value of varB';
    $result->varC   = 'this is the value of varC';

    return $result;
}

$result = load_something();

echo ($result instanceof stdClass)?'Object is stdClass':'Object is not stdClass';
echo PHP_EOL;

print_r($result);

//directly extract a variable from stdClass 
echo PHP_EOL . 'varA = ' . ($result->varA);

//convert to array, then extract
$array = (array)$result;
echo PHP_EOL . 'varA = ' . $array['varA'];
```

Answer (score -3):

stdClass is an object so u can access value from it like

```
echo stdClass->one;
```

Comment: @Petah yes but i think he will have to use foreach too.