# Convert stdClass object to array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I fetch post_id from postmeta as:

```
$post_id = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE (meta_key = 'mfn-post-link1' AND meta_value = '". $from ."')");
```

when i try `print_r($post_id);`
I have array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_id] => 140
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_id] => 141
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_id] => 142
        )

)
```

and i dont know how to traverse it, and how could I get array like this

```
Array
(
    [0]  => 140


    [1] => 141


    [2] => 142

)
```

Any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 347, accepted):

The easiest way is to JSON-encode your object and then decode it back to an array:

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($object), true);
```

Or if you prefer, you can traverse the object manually, too:

```
foreach ($object as $value) 
    $array[] = $value->post_id;
```

Comment: Why can't we just do `$array = json_decode($object,true)` ?

Comment: @akshaynagpal: It'd result in an error because you'll be giving an object to a function that expects a JSON string as its input. In the answer, I am converting the object to a JSON string, and then feeding it as an input to json_decode() so it would return an array (the second parameter being as True indicates an array should be returned).

Comment: i know its too late , but why you not use type casting ... 
**(array) $obj**

Comment: I found `json_decode(json_encode($object), True)` returned a different array compared to the foreach loop. The foreach loop returns the array in the format OP asked for.

Comment: @user3442612: Shouldn't be different. Care to post a working example on eval.in?

Comment: The problem with JSON transformation is with values that are not json-encodable or not standardized, ie. dates.

Comment: @NgSekLong: Not really, no.

Comment: @chhameed: Typecasting won't work if your object has other objects nested inside it. See example - https://eval.in/1124950

Comment: When traversing object manually, how do you access nested values?

Comment: What the exact answer is the list of post_ids , here is the change needed                ``$array = array_values(json_decode(json_encode($object), true));``

Answer (score 69):

Very simple, first turn your object into a json object, this will return a string of your object into a JSON representative.

Take that result and decode with an extra parameter of true, where it will convert to associative array

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($oObject),true);
```

Comment: The problem is with values that are not json-encodable or not standardized, ie. dates.

Answer (score 29):

Try this:

```
$new_array = objectToArray($yourObject);

function objectToArray($d) 
{
    if (is_object($d)) {
        // Gets the properties of the given object
        // with get_object_vars function
        $d = get_object_vars($d);
    }

    if (is_array($d)) {
        /*
        * Return array converted to object
        * Using __FUNCTION__ (Magic constant)
        * for recursive call
        */
        return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $d);
    } else {
        // Return array
        return $d;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect function to change the stdobject to array

Answer (score 25):

You can convert an std object to array like this:

```
$objectToArray = (array)$object;
```

Comment: This is great, but it converts only the first level. If you have nesting you have to do it for all nodes.

Comment: Easy fix it worked

Answer (score 22):

There are two simple ways to convert stdClass Object to an Array

```
$array = get_object_vars($obj);
```

and other is

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($obj), true);
```

or you can simply create array using foreach loop

```
$array = array();
foreach($obj as $key){
    $array[] = $key;
}
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 7):

For one-dimensional arrays:

```
$array = (array)$class;
```

For multi-dimensional array:

```
function stdToArray($obj){
  $reaged = (array)$obj;
  foreach($reaged as $key => &$field){
    if(is_object($field))$field = stdToArray($field);
  }
  return $reaged;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Would you mind expanding your answer a little to explain how it solves the problem?

Comment: For one-dimensional arrays:

    $array = (array)$class;

For multi-dimensional array:

    code from above

Answer (score 6):

While converting a STD class object to array.Cast the object to array by using **array** function of php.

Try out with following code snippet.

```
/*** cast the object ***/    
foreach($stdArray as $key => $value)
{
    $stdArray[$key] = (array) $value;
}   
/*** show the results ***/  
print_r( $stdArray );
```

Comment: This will convert the outer object to an array, but if any of the properties are also objects they won't be converted.

Comment: As per the OP's question he has one level of object structure. For next levels you have to add another foreach loop.

Answer (score 5):

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT ...", ARRAY_A);
```

ARRAY_A is a "output_type" argument. It can be one of four pre-defined constants (defaults to OBJECT):

```
OBJECT - result will be output as a numerically indexed array of row objects.
OBJECT_K - result will be output as an associative array of row objects, using first columns values as keys (duplicates will be discarded).
ARRAY_A - result will be output as an numerically indexed array of associative arrays, using column names as keys.
ARRAY_N - result will be output as a numerically indexed array of numerically indexed arrays.
```

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: this is the only suggested way in WordPress world.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
$aInitialArray = array_map(function($oObject){
    $aConverted = get_object_vars($oObject);
    return $aConverted['post_id'];
}, $aInitialArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have an array and array element is `stdClass` item then this is the solution:

```
foreach($post_id as $key=>$item){
    $post_id[$key] = (array)$item;
}
```

now the `stdClass` has been replaced with an array inside the array as new array element

Answer (score 1):

Using the ArrayObject from Std or building your own

> (new \ArrayObject($existingStdClass))

you can use the build in method on the new class:

> getArrayCopy()

or pass the new object to

> iterator_to_array

Comment: If `$existingStdClass` has a property that is another `stdClass` then that property remains a stdClass in resulting array. If you need something that works recursively then it seems you need to use the json techniques

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume $post_id is array of $item

```
$post_id = array_map(function($item){

       return $item->{'post_id'};

       },$post_id);
```

**strong text**

Comment: This is more simply accomplished with `array_column()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a function `myOrderId($_GET['ID']);` which returns multidimensional OBJ. as a **String**.

None of other 1 liner wokred for me.

This both worked:

```
$array = (array)json_decode(myOrderId($_GET['ID']), True);

$array = json_decode(json_decode(json_encode(myOrderId($_GET['ID']))), True);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with this as my stdClass had stdClasses within them repeatedly. This function recursively converts all elements to an array:

```
$newArray = objectToArray($oldArray)

function objectToArray($data) {
    // If the element being looked is an object convert to an array
    if(is_object($data)) {
      $data = get_object_vars($data);
    }
    // If the element is an array, iterate though it and call the function again on each item
    if(is_array($data)) {
        foreach($data as $key=>$value){
            $data[$key] = objectToArray($value);
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: This is certainly the long way of doing what the accepted answer achieves in a single line of code.

Comment: @mickmackusa Maybe but the accepted answer didn't work for me.

Comment: I don't understand how this could be.  Perhaps prove that claim with a 3v4l.org demo so that we can see the troublesome data.