# issue while converting stdclassobject to array in php

Tags: php

I have an array inside which I have stdclassObjects. I need to convert those stdClassObjects to arrays. Below is the array:

```
Array
(
    [serial] => #253
    [details] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Department] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [value] => CI DATA CENTER
                )

            [City] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [value] => NYC
                )

        )

    [owner] => Drey
)
```

Could somebody please assist me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495068/convert-stdclass-object-to-array-in-php

Comment: This array is different. I tried all the solutions displayed over there. Didn't work.

Comment: Do you want an array back or just the values? Also what have you tried so far? Because the link provided by Abhik should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I want an array back. I've tried several things. One of them: the function involving get_object_vars. I searched here itself before posting my question. Didn't help.

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476876/how-do-i-convert-an-object-to-an-array/2476954#2476954)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The super lazy way is [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/json_decode) and [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/json_encode):

```
$multiDimArray = json_decode(json_encode($multiDimObject), true);
```

The documentation on [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/json_decode) specifies the second parameter being:

> **assoc**
>   When `TRUE`, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertStdClassToArray($stdClass) {

    $outputArray = [];

    if (is_array($stdClass) || !empty($stdClass)) {

        foreach ($stdClass as $field => $value) {

            $outputArray[$field] = $this->convertStdClassToArray($value);

        }
    }
    return $outputArray;
}
```

Comment: 1. `foreach ($stcClass` -> `foreach ($stdClass` 2. Needs moar recursion.