# DataTables warning: table id=dataTables - Ajax error. 404 Not Found

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, datatables

I am trying to get data from a MySQL database through PHP & Ajax to be displayed in a table by using DataTables. I am using XAMPP 1.8.3

This is part of my html code:

```
<table id="dataTables-melate" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Concurso</th>
                                        <th>R1</th>
                                        <th>R2</th>
                                        <th>R3</th>
                                        <th>R4</th>
                                        <th>R5</th>
                                        <th>R6</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>

                                <tfoot>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Concurso</th>
                                        <th>R1</th>
                                        <th>R2</th>
                                        <th>R3</th>
                                        <th>R4</th>
                                        <th>R5</th>
                                        <th>R6</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </tfoot>
</table>
```

This is my php script (**now edited and working**):

```
    //default_chart_numbers.php
    $loteria='revancha';
    $lotto = new Lotto();

    $ultimos_resultados=$lotto->last_results($loteria,20);

    //echo json_encode($ultimos_resultados);
/*Formatting the output to a non associative array*/
function objectToArray($d) 
{
    if (is_object($d)) {
        // Gets the properties of the given object
        // with get_object_vars function
        $d = get_object_vars($d);
    }

    if (is_array($d)) {
        /*
        * Return array converted to object
        * Using __FUNCTION__ (Magic constant)
        * for recursive call
        */
        return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $d);
    } else {
        // Return array
        return $d;
    }
}

$new_array = objectToArray($ultimos_resultados);
//echo '<pre>',print_r($new_array),'</pre>';

$result = array();
echo '[';
foreach ($new_array as $new_array2) {
    echo '[';
    foreach ($new_array2 AS $value){
        echo $value;
        if($value!==end($new_array2)){ //referencias: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8780881/1883256
            echo',';
        }
    }
    echo ']';//referencias: http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-access-php-array-and-multidimensional-nested-arrays-code-syntax/
    if($new_array2!==end($new_array)){
        echo ',';
    }else{ echo '';}
}
echo ']';
```

This is how the output data of the PHP script looks like (**now with the new change**):

```
[[2738,11,12,28,30,50,54], ... ,[2757,32,34,35,36,50,55]]
```

And here is the jQuery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTables-melate').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": {
            "url":"ajax/default_chart_numbers.php",
            "type": "POST"
        },
        "columns":[
            {"data": "concurso"},
            {"data": "R1"},
            {"data": "R2"},
            {"data": "R3"},
            {"data": "R4"},
            {"data": "R5"},
            {"data": "R6"}
        ]
    });
} );
</script>
```

When i load the page (in Firefox), I get this error:
*DataTables warning: table id=dataTables-melate - Ajax error.*
Firebug tells there's this error as well: *404 Not Found*

What am i missing?
I've been struggling with this since so long :/

Comment: I get the same error on chrome :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is going to be a somewhat different approach to using AJAX with DataTables, and hopefully it will help some, because it's much less code.

When using AJAX and adding data to DataTables I usually go this route:
1) echo json_encode on the server side just like you are doing.
2) in the success method of my ajax call I would have this:

Where "column_data" is basically just an array of the data values that correspond
to each column. DataTables automatically adds data this way by counting 
how many values are in this array and pushing each value (column data) to the row 
based on the index in the array. 
So basically you just need just to make sure the number of columns you have 
equals the size of this array, and also make sure that in this array, your data
is in the correct order that you want it to be displayed.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "your_path",
    type: "post_or_get",
    success : function (resp){
        // would look something like ['val1','val2', 'etc']
        var column_data = $.parseJSON(resp);

        // adding data to datatables
        // if column_data is 1 row
        $('your_table_element').dataTable().fnAddData(column_data);

        // to add multiple rows (array of arrays, just loop)
        for (var j=0;j<=column_data.length-1;++j){
            // adding each row with its column data
            $('your_table_element').dataTable().fnAddData(column_data[j]);
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, ex) {
      console.log(textStatus + "," + ex + "," + jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});
```

So in PHP you don't really need the return data to be an associative array. This is how I'm currently implementing it and it works fine for me.

Note: A common error with this method is the length of the return data array not equaling the number of columns you have. So make sure they are equal. If they are not, you'll probably see an error from DataTables saying hinting that a column doesn't exist etc, etc.

Comment: I tried it, but now i get the following error: _DataTables warning: table id=dataTables-melate - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0_ Now the table looks fine, but empty. And it has encountered the 20 values it is supposed to show (because in the table it says: _showing 10 of 20 values_).

Comment: Is your return data an array of arrays? I think that's why it's saying  `unknown parameter'0'` it must be looking at your first row of data at index 0. fnData() only adds a single row, I forgot to mention that. I'll add that to the edit. So to use fnData() you would just need to iterate through your result set and call that each time, I'll update the post with one hang on.

Comment: alright check the EDIT. make sure you comment out the part you don't need (the loop or the single line in the success method). You shouldn't need both.

Comment: All right. I tried it with the loop and commented the single line. I still get the same error, but now this error appear 20 times more. It starts with `unknown parameter '0' for row '0'` and then the javascript alert goes on showing `unknown parameter '0' for row '20'` and on until the `unknown parameter '0' for row '39'`

Comment: Edited: All right. I tried it with the loop and commented the single line. I still get the same error, but now this error appear 20 times more. It starts with `unknown parameter '0' for row '0'` and then the javascript alert goes on showing `unknown parameter '0' for row '1'` and on until the `unknown parameter '0' for row '19'`

Comment: can you show what your "column_data" array looks like after its been parsed?

Comment: By using console.log and firebug it looks the same: `[{"concurso":"2738","R1":"11","R2":"12","R3":"28","R4":"30","R5":"50","R6":"54"},{"concurso":"2739","R1":"10","R2":"14","R3":"36","R4":"49","R5":"51","R6":"54"},{"concurso":"2740","R1":"3","R2":"9","R3":"21","R4":"27","R5":"46","R6":"48"}` and alert(column_data) displays: `[object Object] ... `

Comment: oh yea well that's basically an array of associative arrays. On the server side if you can make it non associative (remove the keys) it should work. So it would look like `[[2738,11,12,28,30,etc], [2739,10,14,etc]]`

Comment: All right, i will give it a try. I am checking how to achieve this by looking at this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19495118/1883256)

Comment: I am checking this [link](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-access-php-array-and-multidimensional-nested-arrays-code-syntax/) to format the data within brackets []. I am checking out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1070256/1883256) as well.

Comment: Well, this is actually a better useful answer to format the non associative array: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8780881/1883256)

Comment: One more thing: I want to add a leading zero to one single digit numbers (because if your search for a number "5", you get results such as "25, 35,50,55"...) but when i do this it does not work because adding a leading zero changes a javascript "number" to a "string". So JSON.parse returns an error expecting numbers (eg: 4) but instead sees a string (eg: "04"). How could i fix this?

Comment: That is probably more suitable for another question, but really while iterating on the js side, just do `Number(your_variable)` and it should cast it as an integer.