# Getting a "syntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or ']' after array element at line x column x" when adding a leading zero to single digit numbers

Tags: php, ajax, json, datatables

i am using dataTables to display data from a MySQL database by using PHP, Ajax, and jQuery.
The data i am showing are numbers and everything works fine.

Here is my php script

```
require_once '../core/init4ajax.php';
$loteria=$_POST['loteria'];

$lotto = new Lotto();

$ultimos_resultados=$lotto->last_results($loteria,20);

function objectToArray($d) 
{
    if (is_object($d)) {
        // Gets the properties of the given object
        // with get_object_vars function
        $d = get_object_vars($d);
    }

    if (is_array($d)) {
        return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $d);
    } else {
        // Return array
        return $d;
    }
}

$new_array = objectToArray($ultimos_resultados);

$result = array();
echo '[';
foreach ($new_array as $new_array2) {
    echo '[';
    foreach ($new_array2 AS $value){
    /********The following piece of code is used to add a leading zero to single digit numbers********/
    /*if (1 == strlen($value)) {
        $zero=0;
        $value = $zero.$value;
    }*/
        echo $value;
        if($value!==end($new_array2)){ //referencias: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8780881/1883256
            echo',';
        }
    }
    echo ']';//referencias: http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-access-php-array-and-multidimensional-nested-arrays-code-syntax/
    if($new_array2!==end($new_array)){
        echo ',';
    }else{ echo '';}
}
echo ']';
```

Here is the output sample of the php script:

```
[[2740,3,9,21,27,46,48],[2741,3,4,13,22,27,29], ... ,[2757,32,34,35,36,50,55]]
```

And here is the ajax code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/default_chart_numbers_table.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {loteria: 'melate'},
    success : function (resp){
        // would look something like ['val1','val2', 'etc']
        var column_data = $.parseJSON(resp);
        //alert(column_data);
        // adding data to datatables
        for (var j=0;j<=column_data.length-1;j++){
            // adding each row with its column data
            //iterating values to add leading zeros to single digits:

            $('#dataTables-melate').dataTable().fnAddData(column_data[j]);
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, ex) {
      console.log(textStatus + "," + ex + "," + jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});    


} );
```

I have realized that i want the single digit numbers to be lead by a zero, e.g. *4*, should be shown as *04*.

By adding the code in order to add a leading zero (this piece of code is already in my php code but commented):

```
if (1 == strlen($value)) {
            $zero=0;
            $value = $zero.$value;
        }
```

Now the php code returns the array the way i want it:

```
[[2740,03,09,21,27,46,48],[2741,03,04,13,22,27,29], ... ,[2757,32,34,35,36,50,55]]
```

however, now from the ajax script i get the following error:

*SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or ']' after array element at line 1 column 9 of the JSON data*

and the data is no longer displayed in the dataTables.

Why is this happening? How can i fix it?

I HAVE FIXED IT:
I just had to add double quotes to those single edit numbers:

```
if (1 == strlen($value)) {
    $zero=0;
    $value = '"'.$zero.$value.'"';
}
```

And that did the trick! ☺

Comment: Why not use `json_encode()` in your PHP script?

Comment: because it didn't work that way. Alex helped me with this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23692858/1883256)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need leading zeros for each single digit number?

Comment: @VincentWilkie Because when i look for a single digit number, other unnecesary results appear. For example, if i search for a number "5", the numbers such as 50, 51, ... 59, will appear as well. If i search for a number 10, only rows with that number will appear. That is why i want a leading zero. Should you have any other suggestion, i'll be glad to know! :)

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use `echo json_encode($multi_dimensional_array)` in your PHP script?

Comment: All right, i have just fixed it! I edited my script above for more detail ;)

Answer (score 1):

Adding a leading zero changes a javascript "number" to a "string". So JSON.parse returns an error expecting numbers (eg: `4`) but instead sees a string (eg: `"04"`).

In the picture below, you can see that I have ran two commands that try to parse a string into JSON.  In the first command, the second item in the first array is `03` and outputs a `SyntaxError`.  In the second command, The `03` was changed to `3` and now it parses properly.

[image: JSON.parse example]

I would recommend researching how to add data to the datatable without leading zeros in order for the table to show up properly and then change how the numbers **are viewed/displayed**

I would also recommend researching [`json_encode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to echo json from PHP.

I use [`json_encode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to echo json from PHP all the time to make sure I get the proper data output when making AJAX calls.

Comment: How could i treat all values as strings? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the leading zeros. This is because you treat the output as JSON, which it is *not*. It is an array of arrays. The error is caused by the line :

```
var column_data = $.parseJSON(resp);
```

Try test the output / supposed JSON with http://jsonlint.com. Example how it could work :

```
var column_data = [
     [2740,3,9,21,27,46,48],
     [2741,3,4,13,22,27,29],
     [2757,32,34,35,36,50,55]
];

var dataTable = $('#dataTables-melate').dataTable()

for (var j=0;j<=column_data.length-1;j++){
  // adding each row with its column data
  //iterating values to add leading zeros to single digits:
  dataTable.fnAddData(column_data[j]);
}
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/jPLSf/**