# Special work with array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, facebook-php-sdk

I want to do something with PHP arrays. I wrote a function to do something which I will say. My input array is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [message] => Automated XML Site Map Generator
http://pastebin.com/xjJe38dp
            [id] => 103114753133019_371405176303974
            [from] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 735588533186829
                    [name] => Mohammad Mostafa Shahreki
                )

            [created_time] => 2013-04-26
            [updated_time] => 2013-04-26
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [message] => Simple but powerful DB class
http://pastebin.com/1qgxUrwX
            [id] => 103114753133019_371404696304022
            [from] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 735588533186829
                    [name] => Mohammad Mostafa Shahreki
                )

            [created_time] => 2013-04-26
            [updated_time] => 2013-04-26
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [message] => Convert Existing DB to Unicode
http://pastebin.com/pHu08cPs
            [id] => 103114753133019_371404609637364
            [from] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 735588533186829
                    [name] => Mohammad Mostafa Shahreki
                )

            [created_time] => 2013-04-26
            [updated_time] => 2013-04-26
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [message] => thanks mosthafa ,,,, for adding me to this group
            [id] => 103114753133019_103333343111160
            [from] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 10155092057165556
                    [name] => HalF PixeL
                )

            [created_time] => 2011-10-11
            [updated_time] => 2011-11-21
        )
)
```

I want to save each data in my MySQL database. For example I want to save **message,id,from->name,created_time** by a function. I tried to write a foreach loop but I couldn't find a way to add from->name, it's a stdClass and can't use it with **['from']['name']**. could you tell me how I can do this?

Comment: ['from']->name, name is an attribute

Comment: Possible duplicate -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495068/convert-stdclass-object-to-array-in-php

Comment: hey. i have an array like that!!!! as you know i can't use each other near them. What should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have that entire array saved as a variable, `$array`, try:

```
$array[0]->from->name;
```

And your function can look something like so:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $inputArray.count(); $i++) {
  $message = $inputArray[$i]->message;
  $id = $inputArray[$i]->id;
  $name = $inputArray[$i]->from->name;
  $created = $inputArray[$i]->created_time;

  // Store the record as you want.
}

// Alternatively, a foreach loop
// See: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php
foreach ($inputArray as $entry) {
  $message = $entry->message;
  $id = $entry->id;
  $name = $entry->from->name;
  $created = $entry->created_time;

  // Store the record as you want.
}
```

Comment: I told you i want to write a function that save all data. this works but i cant save each other in a function

Comment: You can use a `for` loop to loop through the elements of the array. I've edited my answer to include an example.

Comment: hey dear. it's not Just ** message,id,form->name,created_time ** it's a dynamic function. :| is there any way for it:|

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not quite understanding what you mean. Are you saying that there can be a variable number of properties for each object in the array?

Answer (score 0):

Objects' attributes are accessed with the '->' operator (unless you implement ArrayAccess interface). You should get your sender name like so:

```
$var[0]->from->name
```

Optionally you can convert it to array:

```
$from = (array) $var[0]->from;
echo $from['name'];
```

Comment: I know all of it. as you know, I want to write a dynamic function that gives an array and add it into mysql database so what should i do now ?