# soap response convert to json or array from webservice in php

Tags: php, json, soap

How do i convert below following `xml` print_r to `array`:

```
stdClass Object ( [getStateListResult] => stdClass Object ( [any] => 1Andaman and Nicobar Islands2Andhra Pradesh4Arunachal Pradesh5Asia-Pacific6Assam9Bihar10Chhattisgarh11Delhi12Goa13Gujarat16Haryana17Himachal Pradesh18Jammu and Kashmir19Jharkhand20Karnataka21Kerala22Madhya Pradesh23Maharashtra24Manipur25Meghalaya26Nagaland28Orissa29Puducherry / Pondicherry30Punjab31Rajasthan32Sikkim33Tamil Nadu34Tripura35Uttar Pradesh36Uttarakhand / Uttaranchal37West Bengal39Chandigarh (UT)40Dadra and Nagar Haveli (UT)41Daman and Diu (UT)42Lakshadweep (UT)43Mizoram44NEPAL ) )
Array ( [0] => 1Andaman and Nicobar Islands2Andhra Pradesh4Arunachal Pradesh5Asia-Pacific6Assam9Bihar10Chhattisgarh11Delhi12Goa13Gujarat16Haryana17Himachal Pradesh18Jammu and Kashmir19Jharkhand20Karnataka21Kerala22Madhya Pradesh23Maharashtra24Manipur25Meghalaya26Nagaland28Orissa29Puducherry / Pondicherry30Punjab31Rajasthan32Sikkim33Tamil Nadu34Tripura35Uttar Pradesh36Uttarakhand / Uttaranchal37West Bengal39Chandigarh (UT)40Dadra and Nagar Haveli (UT)41Daman and Diu (UT)42Lakshadweep (UT)43Mizoram44NEPAL )
```

Comment: `$array =  (array) $yourObject;` Any more questions?

Comment: This may solve your issue.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495068/convert-stdclass-object-to-array-in-php

Comment: @KirenSiva not it's not working please help me

Comment: I want statid and state name as key value pair in arrary...please help me plzzzz

Comment: @Rizier123 Plsease have look on output......

Comment: U guys are worthless ....there is no one who can help me