# how to convert stdClass Object in to an array

Tags: php, arrays, object, stdclass

I want to get the names of stdClass Object.

```
"Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 179111965447818
            [name] => foot ball
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 103992339636529
            [name] => Cricket
        )

)
```

> Wishes out put:
>
> array("foot ball","Cricket")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert stdClass object to array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495068/convert-stdclass-object-to-array-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried this and it worked for me

```
$sports=array();
foreach($sport as $key=>$val){
     $sports[$key] =$val->name; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is hard to understand, and you clearly haven't tried it. Here's the answer anyways champ.

```
$array = array();
foreach($obj as $item) {
    array_push($array, $item->name);
}
```

The data will be in `$array`.

Answer (score 0):

try a loop and create a new array

```
$newarr = array();
foreach($arr as $v) {
 $newarr[] = $v->name;
}
print_r($newarr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArray=array();
foreach($array as $valArray){
 //$valArray  has all the value that you required and
 // $valArray['name'] is actually what you need
$newArray=$valArray['name'] ;
}
```

$newArray has what you require.