# How do I create CSV file with PHP arrays?

Tags: php, csv

I read official phpnet resources but I can't.

I have 2 arrays.

**First array :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => KDS-1655B
    [1] => KS-9916
    [2] => KDS-1197
    [3] => KDS-4164
    [4] => MRK-1994
    [5] => KDS-9773
) // LONG ARRAY, THIS IS EXAMPLE
```

**Second array:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => PRODUCTNAME1
    [1] => PRODUCTNAME2
    [2] => PRODUCTNAME3
    [3] => PRODUCTNAME4
    [4] => PRODUCTNAME5
    [5] => PRODUCTNAME6
) // LONG ARRAY, THIS IS EXAMPLE
```

Now, I want to create CSV file with 2 headers and 2 columns.
I tried this:

```
$data = array(
    array($first_array, $second_array), // ARRAY CONTENTS
$filename = 'mycsv' . '.csv';
$delimiter = ',';

$f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');

$headings = array('firstheader', 'secondheader',); // HEADERS

fputcsv($f, $headings, $delimiter);

foreach($data as $row) {
    fputcsv($f, $row, $delimiter);
}


fseek($f, 0);

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');

fpassthru($f);

fclose($f);

exit();
```

But all arrays are generating in single header. What can I do about this issue?
Thanks, Regards.

Comment: You can check [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35364528/write-a-csv-file-from-a-php-array/74366235#74366235

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For explanations purpose, I'll reduce the data to:

`$first_array`:

```php
Array {
  [0]=> KDS-1655B
  [1]=> KS-9916
}
```

`$second_array`:

```php
Array {
  [0]=> PRODUCTNAME1
  [1]=> PRODUCTNAME2
}
```

The way you fill `$data` is wrong, because `$data = array($first_array, $second_array);` will give you:

```php
Array {
  [0]=> Array {
    [0]=> KDS-1655B
    [1]=> KS-9916
  }
  [1]=> Array {
    [0]=> PRODUCTNAME1
    [1]=> PRODUCTNAME2
  }
}
```

While you need:

```php
Array {
  [0]=> Array {
    [0]=> KDS-1655B
    [1]=> PRODUCTNAME1
  }
  [1]=> Array {
    [0]=> KS-9916
    [1]=> PRODUCTNAME2
  }
}
```

If I remember correctly, PHP doesn't provide any function to generate this kind of concatenation, you have to code it yourself, for example like this:

```php
$data = array();
$size = count($first_array);
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    $data[] = array( $first_array[$i], $second_array[$i] );
}
```

And you're done. The resulting CSV will be something like:

```
KDS-1655B,PRODUCTNAME1
KS-9916,PRODUCTNAME2
```

---

**Your *fixed* code**

```php
$filename = 'mycsv' . '.csv';
$delimiter = ',';
$data = array();
$size = count($first_array);
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    $data[] = [ $first_array[$i], $second_array[$i] ];
}

$f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');

$headings = array('firstheader', 'secondheader'); // HEADERS

fputcsv($f, $heading, $delimiter);

foreach($data as $row) {
    fputcsv($f, $row, $delimiter);
}
fseek($f, 0);

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');

fpassthru($f);
fclose($f);
exit();
```

---

**Another code**

```php
$csv_filename = 'mycsv.csv';
$csv_header = array('firstheader', 'secondheader');

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $csv_filename . '";');

$fp = fopen('php://memory', 'w');

fputcsv($fp, $csv_header);

$size = count($first_array);
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    fputcsv($fp, [ $first_array[$i], $second_array[$i] ]);
}

fseek($fp, 0);
fpassthru($fp);

fclose($fp);

exit();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am calling this arrays from API. Actually, there are at least 300 values.

Comment: That's just an example based on the data and code in your question. I was going to comment it

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I edited my post.

Comment: you can also do it in a single loop. build the array for the row just before the `fputcsv` you don't need the intermediate `data` array

Comment: `for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {fputcsv($f, [ $first_array[$i], $second_array[$i] ], $delimiter);}`

Comment: @Tuckbros, You're right, that would be the way to go, if not for explaining Omer's error ;-)

Comment: omg, I tried a simple array, it worked! I thanks a lot. @Fravadona