# An error of object of type stdClass as array?

Tags: php

I got this error and here's my code I'm trying to display a table with a linked title but I tried to use pagination and I got this error

```
foreach ($actor as $projects ) {
       echo '<tr><td><a href="'.
       base_url('show_project?id='.
       $projects['proj_id']).
       '">'.
       $projects['title'].
       '</td><td>'.
       $projects['abbrev'].
       '</td><td>'.
       date('F d, Y (h:i A)', strtotime($projects['date_uploaded'])).
       '</td><td>'.
       $projects['professor'].
       '</td></tr>'
       ;
    }
```

Comment: use `$projects->proj_id` instead of `$projects['proj_id']`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert stdClass object to array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495068/convert-stdclass-object-to-array-in-php)

Comment: where is error?

Comment: Here's the error 
Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Filename: Learning/browse.php

Line Number: 35

Backtrace:

Comment: have you tried what I have mention?

Comment: `foreach ($actor as $projects ) { $projects = get_object_vars( $projects );` if you want to be silly....

Comment: Yes and it diplayed an unexpected ';' error

Comment: try `foreach ($actor as $projects ) {
       echo '<tr><td><a href="'.
       base_url('show_project?id='.
       $projects->proj_id).
       '">'.
       $projects->title.
       '</td><td>'.
       $projects->abbrev.
       '</td><td>'.
       date('F d, Y (h:i A)', strtotime($projects->date_uploaded)).
       '</td><td>'.
       $projects->professor.
       '</td></tr>'
       ;
    }`

Comment: It worked. Thank you. How can I commend you

Comment: I write answer, you can accept that.

Answer (score 0):

you should access by `->`

```
foreach ($actor as $projects) {
    echo '<tr><td><a href="' .
    base_url('show_project?id=' .
            $projects->proj_id) .
    '">' .
    $projects->title .
    '</td><td>' .
    $projects->abbrev .
    '</td><td>' .
    date('F d, Y (h:i A)', strtotime($projects->date_uploaded)) .
    '</td><td>' .
    $projects->professor .
    '</td></tr>'
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is you have an object instead of an array. To fix that access your object like so `$projects->title`.

I have cleaned up the code, mainly using `"$object"` interpreted strings.

```
// your data should be changed to something like foreach($actor->projects as 
$project) to make more sense
foreach ($actor as $project ) {
    echo generateTableRow($project);
    }

function generateTableRow($project)
{
    $projectUrl = base_url("show_project?id=$project->project_id");
    $date = date('F d, Y (h:i A)', strtotime($project->date_uploaded));

    $tableRow =  '<tr>';
    $tableRow .= "<td><a href=\"$projectUrl\">$project->title</td>"
    $tableRow .= "<td>$project->abbrev</td>";
    $tableRow .= "<td>$date</td>";
    $tableRow .= "<td>$project->professor</td>";
    $tableRow .= '</tr>';

    return $tableRow;
}
```