# how get the value from assoc array using php

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
   Array([0] => stdClass Object([max(Transaction_id)] => 10251))
```

My php sql query returns the answer in this format.
How can i display the only value from this format.
Thanks in advance

Comment: simple way you will convert stdclass to array type, after you can get data easily. for more clarity see this post . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495068/convert-stdclass-object-to-array-in-php

Comment: you can also get sql query result as array as well.post your code here ..

Answer (score 1):

In your query add the `as` then the name of the column that you want to retreive.

`SELECT MAX(COLUMNNAME) AS example example FROM TABLENAME`

And then in your php file

```
echo $result[0]['example'];
```

Comment: @Obulisathish.v if its works well .you need to accept answer.if given code works for you.try to understand stackoverflow rules and docs.thanks

Answer (score 0):

if for some reasons you are unable to convert the sql query you can access to this variable in the following way

```
echo $obj->{"max(Transaction_id)"};
```