# How to set index in array of object?

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

i have an array wk and for this output is

```
[wk] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [qty] => 2
                            [id] => 2
                            [name] => Single 1 Tag Innenraum 2
                        )

                    [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [qty] => 1
                            [id] => 3
                            [name] => test1
                        )

                )

        )
```

but i want to add new index in object ...how can i add it? any idea ...i am trying to do last two days but no any result

i want output like this :

```
[wk] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [qty] => 2
                            [id] => 2
                            [name] => Single 1 Tag Innenraum 2
                            [1] => Array(
                                    [name] => jiya
                                    [sirname] => rathod
                                        )
                            [2] => Array(
                                    [name] => pinal
                                    [sirname] => rathod
                                        )

                        )

                    [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [qty] => 1
                            [id] => 3
                            [name] => test1
                        )

                )
        )
```

i used array_walk and array_push, array_merge function...

i got this error for all above functions

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in**

Comment: if javascript wanted, please add an example in literal notation.

Comment: Convert the object to array, then add index

Comment: Best is to json_encode the object and decode back to array. Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495068/convert-stdclass-object-to-array-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand that `stdClass Object` uses class variable names. So it will not be possible to use number 1 as a variable name. Instead, go for something like:

```
...
[2] => stdClass Object
 (
  [qty] => 2
  [id] => 2
  [name] => Single 1 Tag Innenraum 2
  [one] => Array(
        [name] => jiya
        [sirname] => rathod
      )
  [two] => Array(
        [name] => jiya
        [sirname] => rathod
      )
...
```

Replace the number with a valid variable name, e.g `one` as above.

To add new element, you can call:

```
wk[1][2]->one = Array(
        [name] => jiya
        [sirname] => rathod
      );
```

Which is easily accessible via `wk[1][2]->one`

Answer (score -1):

You could solve this in two ways:

1) Convert object to array

2) Assign new array to the object, naming it "persons" or the like:

```
$wk[1][2]->persons = array(); // Or via foreach, etc.
```

and then use array_push to insert into that array:

```
array_push($wk[1][2]->persons, '...');
```

---

```
[wk] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [qty] => 2
                        [id] => 2
                        [name] => Single 1 Tag Innenraum 2
                        [persons] => Array(
                            [1] => Array(
                                [name] => jiya
                                [sirname] => rathod
                                    ),
                            [2] => Array(
                                [name] => pinal
                                [sirname] => rathod
                                    ),
                         )

                    )

                [3] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [qty] => 1
                        [id] => 3
                        [name] => test1
                    )

            )
    )
```