# PHP code to access MySQL database not echoing

Tags: php, mysql, heroku, mysqli

Sorry to ask what I assume is a fairly simple question.
Okay, so I'm trying to follow https://www.skysilk.com/blog/2018/how-to-connect-an-android-app-to-a-mysql-database/, a tutorial on how to do, well, exactly what it says.
However, my PHP code, when I test it the way they say I should, by loading up "herokuserverbeingused.com/phpcode.php" in my browser, instead of getting the echo it says I should, I instead get nothing.
Here's my code, it's literally just the code from the tutorial modified slightly

```
<?php
//borrowing from don't forget to credit https://www.skysilk.com/blog/2018/how-to-connect-an-android-app-to-a-mysql-database/

$con=mysqli_connect("a heroku server.net","nope","sorry","very secret");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM players";

// Confirm there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    // We have results, create an array to hold the results
    // and an array to hold the data
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    // Loop through each result
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        // Add each result into the results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }

    // Encode the array to JSON and output the results
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}

// Close connections
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I'm using Heroku to host everything because my professor said that would be a good idea, is that what's causing the problem?

Comment: Have you edited the parameters here `$con=mysqli_connect("a heroku server.net","nope","sorry","very secret");` and changed the table `players`?

Comment: If so, Add the following code at the top of the PHP file to display errors `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
display_errors = on;`   or check the `errors_log` file

Comment: Yeah, I edited the params to keep y'all from actually looking at my database lol. Thanks for the advice, I'll add that.

Comment: Update: the error log I can view via heroku log says 'unexpected '=' in filename.php on line 5' when I add that, line five being display_errors = on;. When I remove that line, it returns to having no errors visible via heroku log, but also not echoing anything, or at least not anything visible.

Comment: What code is on line 5?

Comment: I said, line five is display_errors=on. When commented out, the code runs, but it doesn't echo.
I added a error_log("testecho") to the code to see if the code is running at all  and I am getting testecho in heroku log so the code is running, the issue has to be echo

Comment: Try `print_r(json_encode($resultArray));` or `var_dump(json_encode($resultArray););`

Comment: When I do that it returns bool(false) which is completely mystifying.

Comment: From PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php `Returns a JSON encoded string on success or FALSE on failure.`

Comment: Try `print_r( $resultArray );` or `var_dump( $resultArray );`

Comment: That works. It's returning a bunch of data set up like 
    Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [attribute] => value  ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [attribute] => value  ))

I'll go take a look at the documentation for json_encode, see if I can figure out why it won't accept this as input.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out the issue was that the inner rows in $resultArray were stdClass Objects instead of arrays, the solution was to replace `$temparray = $row` with `$tempArray = json_decode(json_encode($row), True);`

Credit to Dan for helping me figure out what the issue was and the guy who answered [Convert stdClass object to array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495068/convert-stdclass-object-to-array-in-php) for showing me the easiest solution