# How to parse stdClass object in php

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass, var-dump

> Using var_dump from an API call give me the output like this

[image]

How to put them into an array? thanks

Comment: Presumably this is the result of `json_decode($api_return_data)`? If so, just change the call to `json_decode($api_return_data, true)` and you will get an associative array instead of an object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert stdClass object to array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495068/convert-stdclass-object-to-array-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to convert it to a json. After which you can use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) with the second parameter  set to `true` which will return an array instead of an `StdObject`.

If the api you're calling simply returns a json itself then you can go ahead and use `json_decode` directly with the second argument set to `true` to yield the same result.

There are other ways, but this is the simplest.

You can check out other questions, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495068/convert-stdclass-object-to-array-in-php) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576762/php-stdclass-to-array).