# How to push array in stdClass array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which I am getting from my database. For instance:

```
$db_record = $this->search_model->search_Employee();
foreach ($db_record as $db_data) {
    echo $db_data->phone_number;
}
```

In above example I am able to fetch the record without any issue, but I want to add other data in `$db_data` afterwards.

```
foreach ($db_record as $db_data) {
    echo $db_data->phone_number;
    $db_data[]['new_value']='prashant';
}
```

but `$db_data[]['new_value']='prashant';` throwing below error

```
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in
```

It will great if someone can help me as struggeling more than 5 hours.

Comment: because your `$db_data` is an object, not an array, so you can not use it as an array: `$db_data[]`.

Comment: `$db_data->foo = 'prashant'`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396033/stdclass-to-array

Comment: Cast it to an array before adding it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

`$db_data->new_value ='prashant';`

Comment: I get the following error: `Attempt to assign property of non-object`

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a new stdClass object:

```
$tmp = new stdClass;
$tmp->new_value = 'prashant';
$db_data[] = $tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach ($agent as $key => $value) {

   $value->any = 'ssds';
}
```

try to use the $value instead key and object

Answer (score -1):

Your $db_data is an object you can't use them like an array. Yout have to add a property to your object and init them with an empty array.

Example:

```
foreach ($db_record as $db_data) {
    echo $db_data->phone_number;
    $db_data->empty_array=array();
    $db_data->empty_array['new_value']='prashant';
}
```

Comment: This is a not a very useful answer. It doesn't go to explain the simplest solution available thus can be really confusing.