# Issue accessing XML data

Tags: php, xml, web-services

I have connected to a web service and received data in XML file format. When I get a `var_dump($response);` I get this array:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["GetBookInfoByISBN"]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (14) {
    ["Success"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["ResponseText"]=>
    string(10) "Book Found"
    ["State"]=>
    string(2) "CA"
    ["GetNumber"]=>
    string(8) "1234"
    ["BookID"]=>
    int(4) "12"
  }
}
```

Now I am trying to get value of the BookID:

```
$soapclient = new SoapClient('http://wsf.com/BookWS/Book.asmx?WSDL');
$params = array('ISBN' => '1111');
$response = $soapclient->GetBookInfoByISBN($params);
var_dump($response);
<form>
    <p><?php echo $response['BookID']; ?></p>
</form>
```

I am getting this error `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array` which obviously means I am not accessing the data correctly.

I appreciate it any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StdClass object is accessed by using `->`

You must access it using `->` since its an object.

Change your code from:

```
echo $response['BookID'];
```

To:

```
echo $response->BookID;
```

**OR**

You can convert [stdClass object to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396033/stdclass-to-array) like:

```
$array = (array)$stdClass;
```

Comment: Shah, I tried using `$response->BookID;` however nothing is being returned ... Any comments?

Comment: I received the objected which I have shown at the beginning of my question.  However when I use `$response->BookID;` no value is being returned!

Comment: What about  $response->GetBookInfoByISBN->BookID; ?

Comment: Again I used `$response->GetBookInfoByISBN->BookID;` and nothing is returned.

Comment: Can i have demo where i can go through your code! ?

Comment: What are you getting by doing print_r($response); ? Asking because $response->GetBookInfoByISBN  gives nothing! Debug this way!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106127/discussion-between-shashank-shah-and-irfana).