# Loop through a string of values that are used in object method

Tags: php, object, for-loop

I have string that contains comma separated email addresses.

I need to add them to my mailer object ($mailin) using the addBcc method. The object supports method chaining.

I have tried to `echo` in a for loop to achieve what I wanted but as expected, it did not work. It gave me 500 error.

Desired result;

```
$mailin = new Mailin('my@mail.com', 'apikey');
$mails = "a@example.com, b@example.com";
$mailin->
    addBcc('a@example.com')->
    addBcc('b@example.com')->
```

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396033/stdclass-to-array cast it to array?

Comment: depending on the mailer addBcc, may allow arrays or strings. if not explode and loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `explode` and a `foreach` loop like so:

```
$mails = "a@example.com, b@example.com";
$bcc = explode(',',$mails);

foreach($bcc as $address){
    $mailin->addBcc(trim($address));
}
```

Comment: Clear and concise.

Answer (score 0):

if you have:

```
$mails = "a@example.com, b@example.com";
```

**you could do** the following to obtain an array with all the separate emails:

```
$mailArray = [];
$result = [];      //this will be the result
list($mailArray) = explode(",", $mails);//here you are separating the emails
foreach ($mailArray as $value)
{
    $result[] = trim($value);//here you are taking out the whitespaces left behind
}
```

And `$result` would be an array full of the emails you are looking to use. **If you want to look inside the array**, you can do:

```
foreach ($result as $value)
{
  echo "-->{$value}<br>";
}
```

And if you want to use it in your previous code, it would look similar to the following:

```
$mailin->
    addBcc($result[0])->
    addBcc($result[1])->
//... rest of your code
```

Comment: wait, are you suggesting eval?

Comment: @Evert I'm not sure what eval is, but after googling it just now I am sure I am not suggesting it. Why? Does my code have elements of that somewhere?

Comment: @Evert I think you might have been confused with the `-->{$value}<br>` string. The `-->` isn't meant to be code, it's part of the string being echoed in a `foreach` loop to show the OP the results he obtained from the code.

Comment: Well, OP is looking to call a method on an object multiple times. Your answer doesn't do that, but instead it echos how that code looks like?

Comment: Ah indeed. I see what you were going for.

Comment: why 2 loops instead of just 1

Comment: @Dagon the second `foreach` loop is just debugging code for the OP to actually see what is inside the array he just made. BTW, what does OP stand for? I know its the user who asked the question, but the initials O.P.?

Comment: @Webeng O.P = Original Poster or Original Post. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_forum#Thread