# Php and JSON : object(stdClass)

Tags: php, json

I have decoded a JSON file into a variable (`$tmp`). `var_dump($tmp)` gives:

```
object(stdClass)#31 (3) {
    ["c"]=> int(2)
    ["r"]=> int(2)
    ["d"]=> object(stdClass)#32 (4) {
                ["1"]=> string(2) "un"
                ["2"]=> string(4) "deux"
                ["3"]=> string(5) "trois"
                ["4"]=> string(6) "quatre"
            }
}
```

I want to retrieve for example "un" so I do `$tmp->d["1"]` but it doesn't work. I've got the following error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in File.php on line 17
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot use object of type stdClass as array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815520/cannot-use-object-of-type-stdclass-as-array)

Answer (score 2):

[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) takes an additional paramater that will turn your json string into an array instead of an object

`json_decode($json_str, true)`

As comment noted, your `d` property of your json object is an object not an array, so you can't access it with array notation (as you see there is an error)

I believe

```
$tmp->d->{'1'}
// "un"
```

should work in accessing it

Comment: This is a workaround. It doesn't answer the question. Why should he turn the string into an array, when it works perfectly fine as an object?

Comment: May I ask you to not answer obvious duplicate questions? Tthose about this error message are already far too many if you take a peek into google results (at least for my taste but I'm sure you won't think much different), instead, why not suggest to close the question as a duplicate? you can also leave some guidance via a comment if you like to be extra helpful to the OP specifically.

Answer (score 0):

php has a default function json_encode and json_decode

```
$arrayOfValues = array();
$jsonString = json_encode($arrayOfValues);
```

and

```
$arrayOfValues = json_decode($jsonString);
```

with this function you can use variabled with json.