# Parsing JSON data from a remote server

Tags: php, json, parsing, bitcoin

I was wondering if there was any way to make a Parser in PHP in which gets the values from this site [`https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker`](https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker) and sets them as variables in php code?

I have looked at php parsers a bit and the only thing I found was parsers that echo all the information on a website.

Comment: If you're wondering about - if there's way to parse, then - yes, it is. So what is your question? Do the whole work? Add specific problem description

Comment: It's seems like a json response to me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since that URL returns a `JSON` response:

```
<?php

$content=file_get_contents("https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker");
$data=json_decode($content);
//do whatever with $data now
?>
```

Comment: I have tried this but for some reason I get an error
<?php
$dataFromPage = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($dataFromPage, true);
echo $data['ticker']['high'];
$tickerHigh = $data['ticker']['high'];
?>

And I get this error  Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\wamp3\www\DROPBOX\Dropbox\FTP\Test2.php on line 5

Comment: by default `json_decode` will give you an object back, if you have to use it as an array then you can use `$data=json_decode($content,true);`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to get the data from the URL and [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/json_decode) to parse the result, because the site you have linked is returning a [JSON](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) array, that can be parsed by php natively.

Example:

```
$bitcoin = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker"), true);
```

In the `$bitcoin` variable you will have an associative array with the values of the JSON string.

Result:

```
array(1) {
  ["ticker"]=>
  array(10) {
    ["high"]=>
    float(844.90002)
    ["low"]=>
    int(780)
    ["avg"]=>
    float(812.45001)
    ["vol"]=>
    float(13197445.40653)
    ["vol_cur"]=>
    float(16187.2271)
    ["last"]=>
    float(817.601)
    ["buy"]=>
    float(817.951)
    ["sell"]=>
    float(817.94)
    ["updated"]=>
    int(1389273192)
    ["server_time"]=>
    int(1389273194)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The data on that page is called **Json** ([JavaScript Object Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)) (its not output as json mime type, but it is formated like json).
If you *know* that the data will be json, you can aquire it as a string from the page (using for example the `file_get_contents` function) and decode it to an associative array with the `json_decode` function:

```
<?php
$dataFromPage = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($dataFromPage, true);
// Then just access the data from the assoc array like:
echo $data['ticker']['high'];
// or store it as you wish:
$tickerHigh = $data['ticker']['high'];
```

Comment: When I use this code I get this error
 Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in  C:\wamp3\www\DROPBOX\Dropbox\FTP\Test2.php on line 5

Comment: @JVarhol are you sure that you have set the second parameter to true to the `json_decode($dataFromPage, true)` function?

Comment: this is my code <?php $dataFromPage = file_get_contents($url); $data = json_decode($dataFromPage, true); echo $data['ticker']['high']; $tickerHigh = $data['ticker']['high']; ?>

Comment: @ProGM I have set it to true, I have included my code above, Is there any other possibility of why it is giving me an error?

Comment: @JVarhol check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815520/cannot-use-object-of-type-stdclass-as-array . Try to cast to array or use print_r($data); after json_decode and check the value of that data

Comment: @JVarhol try to access the data like this: `echo $data->ticker->high; $tickerHigh = $data->ticker->high;`

Comment: @ProGM Seems like that worked. So now I can use the variable $tickerHigh. Is there anyway to set the script to recheck the prices every, say, 10 minutes.

Comment: @JVarhol You can use some [http://davidwalsh.name/php-cache-function](kind of caching mechanism).

Comment: If you are using the script to fetch data and store it, a cronjob could be a good solution.
(Sorry for not responding on earlier comments, just got back and seems you got it sorted, altho it should be an assoc array and not an object).

Comment: @Jite I will look into a cronjob, but currently it seems that it is working. Exactly what does a cronjob do?

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct (would recommend Hanky 웃 Panky answer, cause that one was first) if you got what you needed. :)

Comment: I always mark an answer as correct, but thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 2):

```
<?
function GetJsonFeed($json_url)
{
$feed = file_get_contents($json_url);
return json_decode($feed, true);
}
$LTC_USD = GetJsonFeed("https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_usd/ticker");
$LTC_USD_HIGH = $LTC_USD["ticker"]["last"];

$BTC_USD = GetJsonFeed("https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker");
$BTC_USD_HIGH = $BTC_USD["ticker"]["last"];
?>
```