# "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" while appending data to json payload

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to append a new object to a JSON array using PHP.

The JSON:

```
{
   "maxSize":"3000",
   "thumbSize":"800",
   "loginHistory":[
   {
      "time": "1411053987",      
      "location":"example-city"
   },
   {
      "time": "1411053988",      
      "location":"example-city-2"
   }
]}
```

The PHP so far:

```
$accountData = json_decode(file_get_contents("data.json"));
$newLoginHistory['time'] = "1411053989";
$newLoginHistory['location'] = "example-city-3";
array_push($accountData['loginHistory'],$newLoginHistory);
file_put_contents("data.json", json_encode($accountData));
```

I keep getting:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

and `null` as the output for the "loginHistory" object upon saving the JSON file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$accountData` is an object, as it should be.  Array access is not valid:

```
array_push($accountData->loginHistory, $newLoginHistory);
// or simply
$accountData->loginHistory[] = $newLoginHistory;
```

Comment: Except `$newLoginHistory` should be an object.

Comment: @AbraCadaver If it contains 'string' keys, it will be when serialized.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that json_decode doesn't return arrays by default, you have to enable this.  See here:
[Cannot use object of type stdClass as array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815520/cannot-use-object-of-type-stdclass-as-array)

Anyway, just add a parameter to the first line and you're all good:

```
$accountData = json_decode(file_get_contents("data.json"), true);
$newLoginHistory['time'] = "1411053989";
$newLoginHistory['location'] = "example-city-3";
array_push($accountData['loginHistory'],$newLoginHistory);
file_put_contents("data.json", json_encode($accountData));
```

If you enabled PHP errors/warnings you would see it like this:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in test.php
>   on line 6

Answer (score 2):

This is a small and simple guide on how to modify a JSON file with PHP.

```php
// Load the file
$contents = file_get_contents('data.json');
 
// Decode the JSON data into a PHP array.
$contentsDecoded = json_decode($contents, true);
 
// Create a new History Content.
$newContent = [
  'time'=> "1411053989",
  'location'=> "example-city-3"
];

// Add the new content data.
$contentsDecoded['loginHistory'][] = $newContent;

 
// Encode the array back into a JSON string.
$json = json_encode($contentsDecoded);
 
// Save the file.
file_put_contents('data.json', $json);
```

A step-by-step explanation of the code above.

1. We loaded the contents of our file. At this stage, it is a string that contains JSON data.
2. We decoded the string into an associative PHP array by using the function json_decode.
   This allows us to modify the data.
3. We added new content to contentsDecoded variable.
4. We encoded the PHP array back into a JSON string using json_encode.
5. Finally, we modified our file by replacing the old contents of our file with the newly-created JSON string.