# How can I access individual values in an associative array in PHP?

Tags: php

I am pulling elements from a standard class object into an assoc array like so:

```
$array = $subjects;
foreach ( $array as $subject ) {

    foreach ( $subject as $prop => $val ) {
        if ( $val !== '' ) {
         echo $prop . ' = ' . $val;
         echo "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

I get the result I expect from above, except what I'd like to do is echo out individual values into a table.

When I do this: 
    echo $subject['day1'];
I get this: "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array."

Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have an array, you have a `stdClass`. Try http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot use object of type stdClass as array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815520/cannot-use-object-of-type-stdclass-as-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's using `StdClass` you'll need to do this:

```
$subject->day1
```

If you want to convert it to an array, have a look at this question: [php stdClass to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576762/php-stdclass-to-array)

Comment: This worked. $subject->day1.  Is it possible to append an index like this: $subject->day.$x ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate over the $array and $array is still an object. Use this:

```
    $vars = get_object_vars($subjects);
```

to get assoc. array from the object $subjects. Then go:

```
foreach ($vars as $name => $value) {
    echo $name . "=" . $value;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: get_object _vars gives an array of 0.

Comment: Then your object is not well defined. Tell me what do you get if you type this:
print "<pre>"; print_r($subjects); print "</pre>";

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [T_id] => 3
            [id] => 27
            [day11] => Maths
            [day12] => English
            [day13] => Free Period
            [day14] => Chemistry
            [day15] => Physics
            [day16] => IPT
            [day21] => Chemistry
            [day22] => Chemistry
            [day23] => Maths
            [day24] => English
            [day25] => Free Period
            [day26] => Physics

Comment: That means that $subjects is already an array, not an object.

Comment: That's what I get. What would be an efficient way to access any individual values? That's what is messing me up.

Comment: Ok, use this:
    $vars = get_object_vars($subjects[0]);

to get assoc. array from the array $subjects first element. Then go:

foreach ($vars as $name => $value) {
    echo $name . "=" . $value;
    echo "<br>";
}

Comment: when I do this: echo $subject->day11; I get expected result. I want to put all values in a table. How to loop through values? If i add an index like this: $x ='11'; echo $subject->day.$x; $x++; will not work. What I want is efficient way to get to each value. Driving me mad.

Comment: If you already have $subject that you can do $subject -> day11 with, then do this:
foreach (get_object_vars($subject) as $day => $subject_name) {
echo "day: " . $day . ", subject name: " . $subject_name; 
}

Comment: OK i have done that and now have a clean looking array.

Comment: Ok, please upvote my comments and accept my answer and upvote my answer if you are satisfied with it. Thanks.