# stdClass error on CodeIgniter Comment System

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm working on a comment section for my blog post in CodeIgniter, I based myself on a tutorial by Brad Traversy and I followed each step carefully but somehow it does not work within my template.

This is show method in my Post Controller:

```
    public function show($slug)
{
    // Get Posts by Slug
    $data['posts'] = $this->Post_model->get_by_slug($slug);

    // Get Comments per Post
    $post_id = $data['posts']['id']; // Here is where I get the error
    $data['comments'] = $this->Post_model->get_comments($post_id);

    // If empty show a 404 error
    if(empty($data['posts'])){
        show_404(); 
    }

    // Load template
    $this->template->load('public', 'default', 'posts/show', $data);
}
```

I created a variable $post_id in order to get the comments for the current post that is being visited by an user. All this should come from my Post_model:

```
    public function get_comments($post_id){

    $this->db->select('username,email,website,body');
    $this->db->from('comments');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('comments', array('post_id' => $post_id));
    return $query->result_array();

}
```

This is where I'm creating the form to add the comment:

```
        <!-- Form -->
    <h4>Add a comment</h4>
    <?php echo validation_errors('<p class="alert alert-danger">'); ?>
    <?php echo form_open('public/comments/add_post_comment/'.$post['id']); ?>
    <!-- Username -->
    <div class="form-group">
    <?php echo form_label('Username', 'username'); ?>
    <?php
        $data = array(
            'id'    => 'username',
            'name'  => 'username',
            'class'     => 'form-control',
            'placeholder'   => 'John Doe',
            'value'         => set_value('username')
        );
    ?>
    <?php echo form_input($data) ?>
    </div>        
    <!-- Email -->
    <div class="form-group">
    <?php echo form_label('E-mail', 'email'); ?>
    <?php
        $data = array(
            'id'    => 'email',
            'name'  => 'email',
            'class'     => 'form-control',
            'placeholder'   => 'JohnDoe@demo.com',
            'value'         => set_value('email')
        );
    ?>
    <?php echo form_input($data) ?>
    </div>      
    <!-- Website -->
    <div class="form-group">
    <?php echo form_label('Website', 'website'); ?>
    <?php
        $data = array(
            'id'    => 'website',
            'name'  => 'website',
            'class'     => 'form-control',
            'placeholder'   => 'https://www.example.com',
            'value'         => set_value('website')
        );
    ?>
    <?php echo form_input($data) ?>
    </div>
    <!-- Comments Body -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_label('Body', 'body'); ?>
        <?php
            $data = array(
                'id'            => 'body',
                'name'          => 'body',
                'class'         => 'form-control',
                'placeholder'   => 'Write here',
                'value'         => set_value('body')
            );
        ?>
        <?php echo form_textarea($data); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- Hidden Input -->
    <?php
        $data = array(
            'name'  => 'slug',
            'value' => $posts->slug,
        );
    ?>
    <?php echo form_hidden($data); ?>
    <!-- Submit Button -->
    <?php echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Add Comment', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')); ?>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

This is the Controller I'm using to add comments to the specific $post_id:

```
    public function add_post_comment($post_id)
{

    // Field Rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|min_length[3]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'trim|required|min_length[3]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

        // Set Message
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'There was an error in proccessing the comment. Please, try again.');

        // Redirect to current page
        redirect(site_url() . 'posts/show/'.$post_id);

    } else {

        // Get Post by Slug
        $slug = $this->input->post('slug');
        $data['posts'] = $this->Post_model->get_by_slug($slug);

        // Create Post Array
        $data = array(
            'post_id'   => $post_id,
            'username'  =>  $this->input->post('username'),
            'user_id'   =>  $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
            'email'     =>  $this->input->post('email'),
            'website'   =>  $this->input->post('website'),
            'body'      =>  $this->input->post('body'),
        );

        // Insert Comments
        $this->Comments_model->add($data);

        // Set Message
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Your comment has been posted');

        // Redirect to same page if form was not successful or submitted
        redirect(site_url() . 'posts/show/'.$post_id);

    }
}
```

All this should work according to some tutorials that I have seen before but this time is not.

[image]

The error comes from my function show. Any idea on how to fix this?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: it already says _cannot use object of type stdClass as an array_, it means `$data['posts']` is an object not an array

Comment: simple sentence: it is not an array, it is object..

Comment: @Kevin Am I going blind or have you forgotten to include the code for your Post_model method - get_by_slug? As you indicate that is the cause of your issue.

Comment: In your show function - add a var_dump($data['posts']); right after your call to get_by_slug so you can eyeball what it's returning.

Comment: I already have the method(get_by_slug) on my Post_model: Here is what I have:
`public function get_by_slug($slug)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->where('slug', $slug);
        $this->db->where('is_published', 1);
        $this->db->limit(1);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return $query->row();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot use object of type stdClass as array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815520/cannot-use-object-of-type-stdclass-as-array)

Comment: I already fixed but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Kevin So "Fixed" means you got it working? If so, what did you do?

Comment: I changed `$post_id = $data['posts']->id;` as you suggested and from there I went into my view and I changed `$comment->username` to `$comment['username']` and it worked like a charm. In addition to that
 `
public function get_comments($post_id){
   
        $this->db->select('*');
  $query = $this->db->get_where('comments', array('post_id' => $post_id));
  
  if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
   return $query->result_array();
  } else {
   return false;
  }
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Ok well as you would have read in the codeigniter users guide - `$query->row()` **will return an object**.

So you would use $data['posts']->id. Which may or may not work with your current PHP Version. I'm open to be corrected on that point.

If you want an **associative array**, as you are attempting to use, then you would use `$query->row_array();`

If you had performed a var_dump like...

```
public function show($slug)
{
    // Get Posts by Slug
    $data['posts'] = $this->Post_model->get_by_slug($slug);

    // Quick Debug to Eyeball what is actually being returned.
    var_dump($data['posts']);
    exit();

    // Get Comments per Post
    $post_id = $data['posts']['id']; // Here is where I get the error
    $data['comments'] = $this->Post_model->get_comments($post_id);

    // If empty show a 404 error
    if(empty($data['posts'])){
        show_404(); 
    }

    // Load template
    $this->template->load('public', 'default', 'posts/show', $data);
}
```

You would see ( and its always a good check when validating your code ) what is being returned by `$this->Post_model->get_by_slug($slug);`

It's a very good idea to know how to "look" at what your variables are and check they are what you think they should be.