# Export CSV Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

i want to export data from my json to csv file but i get this error Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

i want to know please how i can use it as array

```html
public function exportUsers()
 {
  $users = ServicePoint::all()->where("nature", "SP")->toArray();
  $users = ServicePoint::all()->where('statut','<>', 2);

  $arrayCsv = [];
  foreach ($users as $key => $line){
   $arrayCsv[$key][] = $line['name'];
   $arrayCsv[$key][] = $line['lastname'];
   $arrayCsv[$key][] = $line['email'];

  
  }
```

anything can help please

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815520/cannot-use-object-of-type-stdclass-as-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot use object of type stdClass as array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815520/cannot-use-object-of-type-stdclass-as-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As its object it can be accessible with `->` operator

```
foreach ($users as $key => $line) {
    $arrayCsv[$key][] = $line->name;
    $arrayCsv[$key][] = $line->lastname;
    $arrayCsv[$key][] = $line->email;
}
```

Should work.

Comment: i try it befor but not working and now it's working thank you

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are trying to get users based on 2 `where` clauses.

If so, try this

```
$users = ServicePoint::all()->where("nature", "SP")
                            ->where('statut','<>', 2)
                            ->get();
```

Then change these lines

```
$arrayCsv[$key][] = $line->name;
$arrayCsv[$key][] = $line->lastname;
```

and so on.

Comment: is the same problem : Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Answer (score 1):

```
public function exportUsers() {
    $users = ServicePoint::where("nature", "SP")->where('statut','<>', 2)
->all()->toArray();
    $arrayCsv = [];
    foreach ($users as $key => $line){
        $arrayCsv[$key][] = $line['name'];
        $arrayCsv[$key][] = $line['lastname'];
        $arrayCsv[$key][] = $line['email'];
    }
}
```

Try this, it should be working.

Comment: you forget all() is function in servicepoint ..  Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed in ....

Comment: @marozoldik : thanks! I have changed it with all() .