# Get value from array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, named Images and want to get on value from it. This is the data, which my array contains:

```
array(1) {
[924]=>
object(stdClass)#4240 (24) {
["ID"]=>
int(924)
["post_author"]=>
string(1) "1"
["post_date"]=>
string(19) "2011-07-25 15:20:50"
["post_date_gmt"]=>
string(19) "2011-07-25 15:20:50"
["post_content"]=>
string(0) ""
["post_title"]=>
string(17) "Rezept zum Glück"
["post_excerpt"]=>
string(0) ""
["post_status"]=>
string(7) "inherit"
["comment_status"]=>
string(6) "closed"
["ping_status"]=>
string(4) "open"
["post_password"]=>
string(0) ""
["post_name"]=>
string(19) "rezept-zum-glueck-2"
["to_ping"]=>
string(0) ""
["pinged"]=>
string(0) ""
["post_modified"]=>
string(19) "2011-07-25 15:20:50"
["post_modified_gmt"]=>
string(19) "2011-07-25 15:20:50"
["post_content_filtered"]=>
string(0) ""
["post_parent"]=>
int(922)
["guid"]=>
string(60) "/wp-content/uploads/useruploads/rezept-zum-glueck-bild-1.jpg"
["menu_order"]=>
int(0)
["post_type"]=>
string(10) "attachment"
["post_mime_type"]=>
string(10) "image/jpeg"
["comment_count"]=>
string(1) "0"
["filter"]=>
string(3) "raw"
```

}
}

How do I get the value "guid" from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$guid = $your_array[924]->guid
```

You should read the documentation on [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) to learn more about how this work. Also, [what is stdClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

You have an object as the only element in that array.

I think you want to do `$images[924]->guid` depending on if you know the 924 beforehand or not. Otherwise you'll need to do something with a foreach.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hash. How about

```
$obj = (obj) $my_array["924"];
$guid = obj["guid"];
```

I am just guessing here, but might work.