# Handling JSON with Java [-Jackson-]. Cannot deserialize

Tags: java, php, json, jackson

I have a JSON string :

```
"[{\"is_translator\":false,\"follow_request_sent\":false,\"statuses_count\":1058}]"
```

Using PHP's `json_decode()` on the string and doing a `print_r`, outputs :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [is_translator] => 
            [follow_request_sent] => 
            [statuses_count] => 1058
        )

)
```

This shows that it is valid JSON.

However using the Jackson Library gives an error :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize
>   instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token  at
>   [Source: java.io.StringReader@a761fe; line: 1, column: 1]

Here is the simple code :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.type.TypeReference;

public class tests {
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, Object> fwers = mapper.readValue("[{\"is_translator\":false,\"follow_request_sent\":false,\"statuses_count\":1058}]", new TypeReference <Map<String, Object>>() {});
    System.out.println(fwers.get("statuses_count"));

    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong and a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"[{}]" is a list of hashes and you are trying to serialize to a hash.  Try the following.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> fwers = mapper.readValue(yourString, new TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>() {})
```

Comment: There's an error in your code. I don't know where please check.

Comment: Hello, thanks, but say I have nested JSON (as seen here http://pastebin.com/NxQf2mq3 ). I can do this `fwers.get(0).get("status")` to get the status which itself is a json object, how do i get an inner element like `text`?

Comment: ((Map<String, Object>) fwers.get(0).get("status")).get("retweet_count")

If all the casting starts to feel gross, you can use Beans to do your serialization http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDataBinding

Answer (score 2):

Something didn't feel right the first time I looked at the json string. You have [stdClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php) in your json. If I am not mistaken that cannot be translated into Java.

To convert it to json do this:

```
$json = "[{\"is_translator\":false,\"follow_request_sent\":false,\"statuses_count\":1058}]";
$arr = json_decode($json);
var_dump(json_encode( array( (array) $arr[0] ) ) );
```

This will output a different type of json:

```
"[{"is_translator":false,"follow_request_sent":false,"statuses_count":1058}]"
```