# Get first element in PHP stdObject

Tags: php, object, multidimensional-array

I have an object (stored as $videos) that looks like this

```
object(stdClass)#19 (3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#20 (22) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "123"

  etc...
```

I want to get the ID of just that first element, without having to loop over it.

If it were an array, I would do this:

```
$videos[0]['id']
```

It used to work as this:

```
$videos[0]->id
```

But now I get an error "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array..." on the line shown above. Possibly due to a PHP upgrade.

So how do I get to that first ID without looping? Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

**Update PHP 7.4**

Curly brace access syntax is deprecated since PHP 7.4

**Update 2019**

> Moving on to the best practices of OOPS, @MrTrick's answer must be
> marked as correct, although my answer provides a hacked solution its not
> the best method.

Simply iterate its using {}

Example:

```
$videos{0}->id
```

This way your object is not destroyed and you can easily iterate through object.

For PHP 5.6 and below use this

```
$videos{0}['id']
```

Comment: Not really sure about if a documentation explicitly exist for this {} operator. But with experience, I know this is possible. You would be more interested to know that {} operator can be used to iterate through strings as well for eg: $str = "cool";  if you echo $str{0} it will output first letter "C"  and  echo $str{1} would output "o" and so on.. Give a Try..

Comment: With PHP 5.6, this is not possible. You get the following message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: @Dereckson { } works perfectly fine with PHP 5.6 with a little change in syntax by removing -> and using ['objectName']. The final code will be `$videos{0}['id']` . Php 5.4+ gives mores emphasis on objects hence  ->  may not work because  {0}  is already referencing the object.

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack of precision in the previous comment. The fatal error is thrown when using the {0} on an object under PHP 5.6.2, not the ->id.

Comment: @Dereckson probably you are getting an error like this `Trying to get the property of a non object` as {0} still referees to a node on the object. While an identifier ->elementName or ['elementName'] is a must.

Comment: No the error is exactly `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array` which is the error when you try to use a stdClass object as an array. stdClass DOES NOT inherit from base object class, and so doesn't offer this feature.`

Comment: @Dereckson Interesting to know, probably you should post you code on here on stack overflow, we could take a look into it, perhaps we have a solution for it.

Comment: I spoke about the OP code. The solution is to use every other answer on this page, which all work.

Comment: @Dereckson knowing why a code does not works helps us to fix the issues and provide even more better answers. I guess you got my point , you are welcome to use any answer that works.

Comment: it doesn't work on recent PHP versions as you have answered to another question. Instead of "in stdObject", you considered "in any object [inheriting of base object class]". Yet, stdObject isn't such an object in PHP, as it doesn't inherit from the base object class.

Comment: @Dereckson I am confused, wonder how you use the class directly without inheriting 0r creating an object? Its worth giving you code here on a new question

Comment: @Dereckson on an other note this works fine on the latest version tested with PHP 5.6 and works great.

Comment: @sure off course I can, please post your stdObject code we can take it from there.

Comment: My method of accessing the child object was `$videos->{0}` or `$videos->{0}->id` in PHP 5.6.7.   I couldn't see this mentioned here.

Comment: Just want to note that this does not work when a object has defined / string key.

Comment: @MKNWebSolutions even a defined sting or Key has an internal numeric key hence this works.. Or can you provide us with an example?

Comment: @ClainDsilva stdObject as $x = {"xyz":123}, using $x->{0} would not return that first element.

Comment: @MKNWebSolutions you are talking about stdClass which is not our point of discussion we are talking about the base class, PHP differs a lot in Standard Class and Base class.. You should read this to get more insights http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php

Comment: @Clain Dsilva: You're wrong. You cannot iterate over the letters but bytes. It's totally different.

Comment: @JohnSmith Prove me wrong or try this yourself `$str = "Its Possible"; for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) { echo $str{$i}."<br>";}`

Comment: @Clain Dsilva: Deal with string "Grzegrzółka"

Comment: @JohnSmith I see your point on multi byte Unicode chars , so its bytes and not characters... Thanks for proving me wrong..!! I learned something new today.

Answer (score 90):

Both array() and the stdClass objects can be accessed using the
[`current()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) [`key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) [`next()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php) [`prev()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.prev.php) [`reset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) [`end()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php)
functions.

So, if your object looks like

```
object(stdClass)#19 (3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#20 (22) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "123"
  etc...
```

Then you can just do;

```
$id = reset($obj)->id; //Gets the 'id' attr of the first entry in the object
```

If you need the key for some reason, you can do;

```
reset($obj); //Ensure that we're at the first element
$key = key($obj);
```

Hope that works for you. :-)
No errors, even in super-strict mode, on PHP 5.4

---

**2022 Update:**
After PHP 7.4, using `current()`, `end()`, etc functions on objects is deprecated.

In newer versions of PHP, use the [ArrayIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php) class:

```
$objIterator = new ArrayIterator($obj);

$id = $objIterator->current()->id; // Gets the 'id' attr of the first entry in the object

$key = $objIterator->key(); // and gets the key
```

Comment: reset() and end() are nice because you don't need to know the key, just the position (first or last).

Comment: They should have named reset() like first() or something similar to make more sense. This answer is the correct one. The correct answer does not work.

Comment: Moving on to the best practices and OOPS, this answer must be marked as corrected, although my answer provides the solution its not the best method.

Comment: Deprecated: reset(): Calling reset() on an object is deprecated

Comment: Deprecated: key(): Calling key() on an object is deprecated

Comment: Good catch @BeninCA, thank you. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 30):

much easier:

```
$firstProp = current( (Array)$object );
```

Comment: This is great if you don't know the node name.

Answer (score 18):

Correct:

```
$videos= (Array)$videos;
$video = $videos[0];
```

Comment: Good answer, but it's not really helping me navigate through an object, it's just converting it to an array and then navigating it as an array.

Answer (score 8):

`$videos->{0}->id` worked for me.

Since $videos and {0} both are objects, so we have to access id with  `$videos->{0}->id`. The curly braces are required around 0, as omitting the braces will produce a syntax error : unexpected '0', expecting identifier or variable or '{' or '$'.

I'm using **PHP 5.4.3**.

In my case, neither `$videos{0}->id` and `$videos{0}['id']` worked and shows error :

Cannot use object of type stdClass as array.

Answer (score 6):

You could loop on the object maybe and break in the first loop...
Something like

```
foreach($obj as $prop) {
   $first_prop = $prop;
   break; // exits the foreach loop
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Playing with Php interactive shell, Php 7:

```
➜  ~ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $v = (object) ["toto" => "hello"];
php > var_dump($v);
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["toto"]=>
  string(5) "hello"
}
php > echo $v{0};
PHP Warning:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in php shell code:1
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in php shell code on line 1

Warning: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in php shell code:1
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in php shell code on line 1
php > echo $v->{0};
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$0 in php shell code on line 1

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$0 in php shell code on line 1
php > echo current($v);
hello
```

Only `current` is working with object.

Answer (score 0):

the following can be done

```
$rows=null; 
foreach ($result as $rows) break;
```