# php access value of the array inside object

Tags: php, arrays, object

i have an output in a object

it looks like below,

```
stdClass Object
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 14
                [tcaseid] => 11
                [step] => a
                [teststep] => a
                [expected_data] => a
                [actual_result] => a
                [pass_fail] => 1
                [notes] => a
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 15
                [tcaseid] => 11
                [step] => b
                [teststep] => b
                [expected_data] => b
                [actual_result] => b
                [pass_fail] => 1
                [notes] => b
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 16
                [tcaseid] => 11
                [step] => d
                [teststep] => d
                [expected_data] => d
                [actual_result] => d
                [pass_fail] => 1
                [notes] => d
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 17
                [tcaseid] => 11
                [step] => e
                [teststep] => e
                [expected_data] => e
                [actual_result] => e
                [pass_fail] => 1
                [notes] => e
            )

        [id] => 11
        [project_id] => 1
        [title] => title
        [description] => desc
        [module_id] => 1
        [usecaseid] => 1
        [tcaseid] => 5
    )
```

my question is how to get this value `( [id] => 11 )`

i have tried

```
* $data->id

* $data['id'];
```

any help?

Comment: `$data->id` didn't work? how about `echo $data->id;`?

Comment: yes trying echo $data->id; also gives error.

Comment: There is already an answer for this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474446/get-first-element-in-php-stdobject/19921022#19921022

Comment: use get_object_vars() function. `$data = get_object_vars($data); print_r($data);`. i hope this help

Comment: thanks to all. finally worked

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$data[4]['id'];
```

Link For Ref:
http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/php-tip-convert-stdclass-object-to-multidimensional-array-and-convert-multidimensional-array-to-stdclass-object/

Comment: thanks for your reply. actual the size of object is not fixed.