# Get instance of an object

Tags: php, object

I have an object which has multiple instances;

```
object(stdClass)#613 (5) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#426 (24) {
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(30) "Thu Jun 04 14:07:47 +0000 2015"
    ["id"]=>
     ...
```

I want to access a certain instance. I understand I can use a `foreach` or I can cast the object to an array and access the instance I want that way.

[I also realise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19921022/817379) I should be able to access an instance using curly brace notation ( Server is running an old version of PHP - out of my control )

```
$tweets = retrieve_tweets();
if ( isset( $tweets{0}->created_at ) ) {
    ...
```

However I get the error;

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

What am I doing wrong with this notation?

Comment: Tried `$tweets->{0}->created_at`? $tweets is an object, not an array.

Comment: Maybe `$tweets[0]->{'created_at'}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to cast the object to an array in the end as the object properties had been [named as integers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10333200/817379)...