# How can I get the first element from a Countable object?

Tags: php, arrays, object, casting

In PHP I have a [countable object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php).  According to the docs, PHP's `count` function will return the number of items in an array or the number from a Countable object.

My goal is to get the first item from a countable object in the cleanest manner.

`foreach($object as $ob){ $first = $ob; break; }`

This works, but is dreadful.

`$object[0]` complains that `$object` is not an array (which is correct, it isn't an array, it's an object).

`(array)$object[0]` feels equally as bad, but also doesn't work.  Simply returns `null`.

What is the cleanest way to get the first item?

Comment: What methods does to object have? Does it have something like `$object->get(0)` Also, try `(array)($object)[0]`. Countable is supposedly an interface, so the object the implements countable should have some attribute in it, which you can refer to directly `$object->array_in_object[0]`?

Comment: Relevant: [Get first element in PHP stdObject](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9474446/2943403)

Comment: Objects don't typically rely on the order of their properties.  If you want an ordered list, use an indexed array instead of an object.  It is entirely appropriate to contain an array as a property within an object; maybe you'd entertain a better object structure. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable way to "get the first item" from a `Countable` object, because Countables don't necessarily *have* items.

Instead, use `Traversable` (an object that has items you can iterate) or `iterable` (a pseudotype that includes anything you can iterate, including arrays). In that case, your original solution is correct (and is not dreadful):

```
function first(iterable $iterable) {
  foreach ($iterable as $first) {
    return $first;
  }

  // if you get to this point, the $iterable was empty.
  // you might return null or throw an exception,
  //  as appropriate for your use case
}
```

Comment: My suspicion is that the asker will find the replacement of `break` with `return` to be very little improvement in terms of elegance.

Comment: well, that wasn't really meant to placate them. : )  as noted, there's nothing wrong with the solution in the first place. this is just as a function instead of being inline.

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use :

```
$object{0}
```

Comment: The second method doesn't work, as outlined in my question.

Comment: Afraid not, neither worked.  `$object{0}` complains of $object not being an array

Comment: could you please paste the structure of your object ? that would be helpful to solve the issue, because $object{0} should be working just fine