# What is the correct way to access values in multi-dimensional OBJECT in PHP

Tags: php, oop, object

I have an Object like below

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [className] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [attribute] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => Aabir Hussain
                            [phone] => 9555555985
                            [email] => aabir@gmail.com
                            [create_on] => 12-10-2016 12:12:12
                            [status] => Active
                        )

                    [validationMessage] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => no_error
                            [phone] => no_error
                            [email] => Email Already Taken, Please Choose Another One
                            [create_on] => no_error
                            [status] => no_error
                        )

                    [scenario] => create
                )

        )

)
```

**I want to get value of name without using foreach or for loop**

I have tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474446/get-first-element-in-php-stdobject) where they have given different approaches to get values from an Object like below. but nothing is working for me.

```
print_r($arrayMultiIndex[0]); //not working because it is not an array;
print_r($arrayMultiIndex{0}); //not working
print_r($arrayMultiIndex->0); //not working
```

**I am using PHP 7.0.9**

**EDIT**

```
print_r($arrayMultiIndex->{0}); //also not working or
echo $arrayMultiIndex->{0}->className->attribute->name //not working
```

**EDIT For Php Fiddle**
[php fiddle link](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/fwcm-jw2b)

Comment: try this for the attribute name`echo $arrayMultiIndex->{0}->className->attribute->name`.

Comment: print_r($arrayMultiIndex->{0}); //not working

Comment: You need a quota: `echo $arrayMultiIndex->{'0'}->className->attribute->name`

Comment: You mean like this 
echo $arrayMultiIndex->{'0'}->className->attribute->name;
. it is also not working . Giving me error like this 
Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$0 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/practice/techgig_practice.php on line 116

Comment: make a fiddle for better checking...

Comment: as you asked, i have created Php fiddle. Thanks for the help bro

Comment: OK, let me check here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the below link could help you out

[How to access object properties with names like integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333016/how-to-access-object-properties-with-names-like-integers/10333200#10333200)

Basically, Curly-brace syntax for object property access does not work for all-digit keys.

Or instead of simply typecasting the object use my modified version of the function arraytoobject. This only for your specific need. I am converting the key to a string as otherwise it won't be accesible.

```
$arrayMultiIndex = [
     [
    'className' => [
        'attribute' => [
            'name' => 'Aabir Hussain',
            'phone' => 955585,
            'email' => 'aabir@gmail.com',
            'create_on' => '12-10-2016 12:12:12',
            'status' => 'Active'
        ],
        'validationMessage' => [
            'name' => 'no_error',
            'phone' => 'no_error',
            'email' => 'Email Already Taken, Please Choose Another One',
            'create_on' => 'no_error',
            'status' => 'no_error'
        ],
        'scenario' => 'create',
    ] 
]
];
$arrayMultiIndexObject = arrayToObjectNew($arrayMultiIndex);
function arrayToObject($d) {
    if (is_array($d)) {
        /*
        * Return array converted to object
        * Using FUNCTION (Magic constant)
        * for recursive call
        */
        return (object) array_map(__FUNCTION__, $d);
    }
    else {
        // Return object
        return $d;
    }
}
function arrayToObjectNew($array) {
if (!is_array($array)) {
    return $array;
}


if (is_array($array) && count($array) > 0) {
    foreach ($array as $name=>$value) {

        $object = new stdClass();
        if(is_numeric($name))
            $name = (string) $name;

        $name = strtolower(trim($name));
        // if (!empty($name)) {
            $object->$name = arrayToObject($value);
        // }
    }
    return $object;
}
else {
    return FALSE;
}
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($arrayMultiIndexObject->{0}); die;
```

Comment: seems like we can't access this index, either we have to convert it into an array or we have to use a new stdClass then assign values to it.

Comment: Yes that is correct. I hope you are creating this object by simply typecasting? so I would suggest that get an associated array to do that.

Comment: yes i have created this object with typecasting.have a look at fiddle and i use `$jsonConversion = json_decode(json_encode($arrayMultiIndexJson))` then i am able to `print_r($jsonConversion[0]);`

Comment: Please check my edit if you want to use the object only. Although this is not proper coding standard, but based on your requirement either you can use json_decode(json_encode($arrayMultiIndexJson)) but that again is creating an array which you do not want. so you can use the method specified in my edit. Please check.

Comment: Thanks dude. it does not support integer index, so converting it to string is better option.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use foreach and for loop then convert this object into array and filter out 'name' property value and access it in normal way like $arr[0], $arr[1],...
i.e. code given below which is not using foreach and for loop and then getting name property value..

```
//Converting object into array
$arrayMultiIndex_arr = json_decode(json_encode($arrayMultiIndex), TRUE);

//Filtering out name property value from array
$name_array = array_column(array_reduce(array_reduce($arrayMultiIndex_arr, 'array_merge', array()), 'array_merge', array()), "name");

print_r($name_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

As i search everywhere i don't find any feasible solution for you, but i can give you one suggestion to convert the object into array.

```
$arrayMultiIndex = (array)$arrayMultiIndex;
echo $arrayMultiIndex[0]['className']['attribute']['name'];
```

[Online Example](https://3v4l.org/K2jVY) of this code.

please read the whole bunch of answer form [here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333016/how-to-access-object-properties-with-names-like-integers/10333200#10333200)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know i can convert into array then easily access this $arrayMultiIndex[0]['className']['attribute']['name'];
but it will be an headache for me because i always have to convert it into an array.

Comment: Yes i know, The problem is with your Object. Otherwise it will be access easily as i said / suggest earlier.

Comment: did you see the fiddle, i have just typecaste the array to make it Object. Some one said that it is not possible to access because 0 is integer.

Comment: Yes, If you make an stdClass then it is easy to access but you have typecast it so now it is not possible.

Answer (score -1):

$name = reset($arrayMultiIndex)->className->attribute->name;

echo $name;

Comment: Try to add a little more detail around your code to explain what is going on.

Comment: @Toby Did you down vote because I did not include how reset() works?

Comment: It is always useful to explain what your code does, rather than just putting the code there and hoping people understand.