# How to read a array object for a class

Tags: php, arrays

Hi all i have the follow array

```
Classes\Form_Record Object
(
    [sent_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [cw6hwgw] => 11
            [ezlkp6m] => 11
        )

    [fields:protected] => Array
        (
            [cw6hwgw] => Array
                (...
```

And trying to read the vaules from cw6hwgw and  ezlkp6m

What do i need to get the result in php
as we tried  `[sent_data][0]`  which dose not work

Comment: Post the full `Classes\Form_Record` class code.

Comment: Those are protected properties - you aren't supposed to access them directly. See if there are any accessor methods on the class.

Comment: may this can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474446/get-first-element-in-php-stdobject

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get protected property of object in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334355/how-to-get-protected-property-of-object-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

if I understand correctly, you have used an array in the array so you should use two foreach loops, or indicate the number in the array for both arrays.

Comment: No, you misunderstand.... those arrays are protected properties of an object instance, this is not nested arrays

Comment: o, My bad...so the only thing that comes to mind is to use acces getter method

Answer (score 1):

you need to cast the object to array.

sample code:

```
$my_obj =(object) ['sent_data:protected' => ['cw6hwgw' => 11, 'ezlkp6m' => 11 ]];

echo gettype($my_obj)."\n\n";


$to_array_ = (array) $my_obj;

foreach($to_array_['sent_data:protected'] as $k=>$v){
    echo "{$k} = $v \n";
}
```

Comment: interesting when converted to a array i get this  and not  sent_data:protected
Array
(
    [ * sent_data] => Array
        (
            [cw6hwgw] => 11
            [ezlkp6m] => 11
        )

and still cannot read it, not sure if the *  or space before is invaild 
print_r ([ * sent_data])

Comment: use `print_r(get_object_vars($YOUR_OBJECT_VAR));` to get the indexes.