# foreach array error

Tags: php, mysql

I have coded

```
foreach($DB->query($query) as $row){
print_r($row);
```

which is giving result as

```
 stdClass Object ( [follow_date] => 2012-04-17 [status] => 1 [user_id] => 8 ) stdClass Object ( [follow_date] => 2012-04-17 [status] => 2 [user_id] => 9 )
```

but when i am calling  `print_r($row[follow_date]);`, its giving error

**Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /homereports/bespoke_dialing_status.php on line 34**

Can somebody tell what's the problem?

Comment: the same print_r($row[follow_date]);

Comment: Hi, when I am writing echo $status = $row->status;, then it's fine but when I'm writing echo '<tr><td>' . $user_id . '</td><td>' . get_status_by_id($status) . '</td><td>' . $follow_date . '</td></tr>' ; 
it's giving error Catchable fatal error: **Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /home/reports/bespoke_dialing_status.php on line 44** line 44 is **}**

Comment: What does `print_r(get_status_by_id($status));` return? In case it is an object, select the appropriate property by using something like: `get_status_by_id($status)->thePropertyYouWant`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the error, you are trying to use [stdClass](https://stackoverflow.com/q/931407/3287) as an array, which is not possible.

Since `$row` is a [stdClass](https://stackoverflow.com/q/931407/3287) you need to use another syntax to retrieve the date.

```
$date = $row->follow_date;
```

That should give you the result you want.

Answer (score 2):

Use: `$row->follow_date` to access the content.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a way to check But i remember using like `$row->follow_date` on a similar matter.