# PDO Warning and Undefined Method myclassname::bindParams()

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I started over with a project I was working on earlier. With the help of my PHP book and a few people on Stack Overflow, I was able to get rid of a lot of the errors I was getting.

Now, I am left with a warning and a fatal error.  I understand both errors, I am just not sure how to fix the errors I am getting.  Could anyone please help?  I am **not** asking for anyone to write the code or just do everything for me, I just need a point in the right direction.

This is the warning, and it sounds like I need to put __construct somewhere in the uploadFile() method, but again, not sure about this:

> Warning: PDO::prepare() [pdo.prepare]: SQLSTATE[00000]: No error: PDO
>   constructor was not called in C:\xampp\htdocs\files\upload.php on line
>   23

The second, I am just completely lost on what to do about.  I realize what the error is telling me, I just don't know where to start in terms of fixing it.  Here it is:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method upload::bindParam() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\files\upload.php on line 24

If there's anymore information I could provide that would make this easier to answer, please tell me and I will try to get it for you.  I appreciate any help!

**upload.php**

```
  <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require('config.php');

class upload extends PDO
{
    public $conURL, $filename, $tmpname, $filesize, $filetype, $file;

    public function __construct($config) {
        $conURL = "mysql:host=" . $config['host'] . ";dbname=" . $config['db'];
        parent::__construct($conURL, $config['user'], $config['pass']);

    }       

    public function uploadFile() {
        if ($_FILES['file']['size'] >= 2000000) {
           echo "File is too large!"; 
        }
        else {
            $sth = $this->prepare("INSERT INTO uploads (name, type, size, file) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $sth->bindParam(1, $filename);
            $sth->bindParam(2, $filetype);
            $sth->bindParam(3, $filesize);
            $sth->bindParam(4, $file);
            $sth->execute();
        }
    }
}

$upload = new upload($config);

$upload->filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$upload->tmpname = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$upload->filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$upload->filetype = $_FILES['file']['type'];    
$upload->file = $_FILES['file'];


$upload->uploadFile();
```

**config.php**

```
<?php
$config = array(
        'host' => 'localhost', // db host
        'user' => 'root', // db user
        'pass' => '', //db pass
        'db' => 'files' // db name
);
```

Edit: Thanks to everyone here, only one error remains and it is the following:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::uploadFile() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\files\upload.php on line 43

Edit 2: All errors have been resolved, but nothing is being inserted into the database.

Comment: You should use `execute()` and `bindParam()` on a `PDOStatement` object and not the actual `PDO` object, the `prepare()` returns such an object.

Comment: In addition to @KristerAndersson - `class upload extends PDO` - is a great example that you always should prefer composition over inheritance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor should look like:

```
public function __construct($config) {
        $conURL = "mysql:host=" . $config['host'] . ";dbname=" . $config['db'];
        try {
            parent::__construct($conURL, $config['user'], $config['pass']);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $e->getMessage();
        }
}
```

or even

```
public function __construct($config)
{
    $conURL = "mysql:host=" . $config['host'] . ";dbname=" . $config['db'];
    parent::__construct($conURL, $config['user'], $config['pass']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Although, when I replace "return new PDO" with "parent::__construct," it seems to break my uploadFile() method.  It's now saying the method is undefined on line 43 (last line).  What am I missing here?

Comment: @Dustin L.: see comments and another answers. You're calling the method `PDO` doesn't have

Comment: This is the error I am now getting: Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::uploadFile() in C:\xampp\htdocs\files\upload.php on line 43

Comment: @Dustin L.: put 40-45 lines of that file to the question, we cannot guess (append your question with new file version and mark correspondent lines)

Comment: All the code that is in upload.php is posted.  It ends on line 43.

Comment: @Dustin L.: I see the update and I would say that it's not possible that the code throws `Call to undefined method stdClass::uploadFile()` error. It is just impossible. There is a chance you're requesting or modifying a wrong file.

Comment: Lol, thank you, but it is indeed throwing that.  All the code is pasted except for the HTML form.

Comment: @Dustin L.: it's not possible. There is no `stdClass` object there. So double check that you're requesting and/or modifying the correct file, and that your browser didn't cache response

Comment: Well, I found this if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php

Comment: @Dustin L.: I know what `stdClass` is. And I don't see it in your code, I only see `upload` class

Comment: @Dustin L.: check that you're modifying and requesting correct file. The code you've shown **cannot** throw such error

Comment: @Dustin L.: why did you comment out `error_reporting`? It's the most important line of all your file

Comment: @Dustin L.: put `var_dump($upload);` on the 35th and 42th lines (yes, twice) and show output here

Comment: I was testing something.  When it's commented out, I get another error.  The two may or may not be related:

Strict Standards: Creating default object from empty value in C:\xampp\htdocs\files\upload.php on line 36

Comment: I think the constructor is failing and returning stdclass. please see my answer

Comment: @Dustin L.: **IT IS IMPORTANT**. Omg, why the hell do you program in that way?! Do you drive with your eyes closed? :-S (sorry, it just confuses me a lot)

Comment: @mask8: Even if it fails - the object should be of `upload` class

Comment: @Dustin L.: replace your constructor with the 2nd one from my answer, and check for the second time that in my answer there is no `$this->` for `$conUrl`. Wondering why there was no notice for that :-S Or was it?

Comment: var_dump returned null.  

Zerk, I put it back...I was just testing...

I am no longer getting any errors, but nothing is being inserted into the database.

Comment: Update your question with the latest file version

Comment: @Dustin L.: so - there is `object(upload)`, not `stdClass`

Comment: The error I got was stdClass.  

Anyway, nothing is being inserted into the database.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14109/discussion-between-zerkms-and-dustin-l)

Answer (score 1):

well 2 guys pointed another issue, but really point here is you are calling bindParam of PDO subclass. That needs to be `pdostatement` instaed. try:

```
        $sth = $this->prepare("INSERT INTO uploads (name, type, size, file) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $sth->bindParam(1, $this->filename);
        $sth->bindParam(2, $this->filetype);
        $sth->bindParam(3, $this->filesize);
        $sth->bindParam(4, $this->file);
        $sth->execute();
```

Of course you need to fix following errors in your constructor as well.

EDIT:

I guess the constructer is failing and throwing exception. Because $this->conURL is null. Change

```
$conURL = "mysql:host=" . $config['host'] . ";dbname=" . $config['db'];
```

to

```
$this->conURL = "mysql:host=" . $config['host'] . ";dbname=" . $config['db'];
```

Also I changed my previous answer, please see bindparam()'s 2nd parameters.

Comment: Also, OP uses undefined variables, instead of object properties. I'm wondering if there is a single line without errors ))

Answer (score 0):

Because you are extending PDO, so

```
return new PDO($this->conURL, $config['user'], $config['pass']);
```

Should be

```
parent::__construct($this->conURL, $config['user'], $config['pass']);
```