# No Error for Undefined Variable Used in Class Methods in PHP

Tags: syntax, syntax-error, php

I spent more than 10 hours to find out the typo for debugging my PHP program. I expected PHP would produce an error when using an undefined variable. But when it is used as an object in a method, it doesn't. Is there a reason for it?

```
<?php

    $oClass = new MyClass;
    // $oCless->tihs('key', 'taht');    //<-- triggers the error: Notice: Undefined variable
    $oClass->tihs('key', 'taht');
    echo $oClass->arr['key'];

    class MyClass {
        public $arr = array('key' => 'foo');

        function tihs($key, $value) {
            $tihs->arr[$key] = $value;  //<-- this does not cause an error message.
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: the misspelling of 'this' is very confusing

Comment: having a function named 'this' is also very confusing

Comment: undefined values in PHP are not an error. they just produce a warning if you've got the right level of display_errors/error_reporting enabled.

Comment: Make sure your error reporting includes notices, and set up a custom error handler that aborts all processing after any error is reported, whether it is a notice, warning or a real error. Then prepare to fix a lot of code which will suddenly start throwing notices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally if the error reporting level is set to `E_ALL | E_STRICT` (or `E_ALL` as of PHP 5.4.0) it should spit out an E_STRICT error. For instance, this code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$tihs->adrr = 453;
```

Produces:

```
Strict Standards: Creating default object from empty value in [...]
```

Interestingly enough, if you specifically create **an array** instead of an ordinary variable as a property of an object that doesn't exist, e.g.:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$tihs->adrr[25] = 453;
```

No strict standards error is shown! It looks like this could potentially be something PHP folks might want to fix, because I'm not aware this is documented nor I think there's a legitimate reason for this behaviour.

For the record, in both cases regardless of the error a new [stdClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php) is being created on the fly instead, like sberry mentions in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12274353/1329367).

Comment: I hope it will be fixed in the future. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of PHP trickery...

Under the covers, PHP is actually creating an object called `tihs`, adding an array to the object called `arr` and setting `key` to `value`.

Here is a `print_r($tihs);` after the assignment:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [arr] => Array
        (
            [key] => taht
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seemed to have misspelt `$oClass` as `$oCless`

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, $oCless instead of $oClass would give you an undefined variable error. 

Also, "this" is a keyword in most languages and may be in php as well. You should refrain from using it so that it doesn't come out in other languages as a habit. You'll get way more errors if you're using "this" as function and variable names. You wouldn't even get things to compile.