# save parameters of stdClass Object as array

Tags: php

i can't accsess to parameters of bottom array.how can i save  parameters.

```
stdClass Object ( [MsgID] => 11604184 [UserID] => 0 [LinkID] => 0 [NumberID] => 0 [Tariff] => 0 [MsgType] => 0 [Body] => Received sms test2. [Udh] => [SendDate] => 2013-06-08T14:30:22.213 [Sender] => 9352175555 [Receiver] => 30001110000011 [FirstLocation] => 1 [CurrentLocation] => 1 [Parts] => 1 [IsFlash] => [IsRead] => 1 [IsUnicode] => [Credit] => 0 [Module] => 0 [RecCount] => 1 [RecFailed] => 0 [RecSuccess] => 0 [IsMoneyBack] => )

stdClass Object ( [MsgID] => 11603241 [UserID] => 0 [LinkID] => 0 [NumberID] => 0 [Tariff] => 0 [MsgType] => 0 [Body] => Received sms test. [Udh] => [SendDate] => 2013-06-08T14:22:43.293 [Sender] => 9352175555 [Receiver] => 30001110000011 [FirstLocation] => 1 [CurrentLocation] => 1 [Parts] => 1 [IsFlash] => [IsRead] => 1 [IsUnicode] => [Credit] => 0 [Module] => 0 [RecCount] => 1 [RecFailed] => 0 [RecSuccess] => 0 [IsMoneyBack] => )
```

Comment: If you really have to access the properties of an object as though it was an associative array, then cast it to an array using `$myArray =  (array) $myObject;` but why not simply access object properties as properties? `$value = $myObject->MsgID;`

Answer (score 2):

It's not an array, it's an stdClass Object.

- [Predefined Classes](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php)
- [What is stdClass in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php)

You can access object properties using this syntax:

```
echo $obj->MsgID;
```

Or use typecasting to convert stdClass object to array:

```
$array = (array)$obj;
echo $array['MsgID'];
```

Comment: thanks.i used foreach ( $arrMessages as $messages){
   echo  $messages->Body;
    
    echo "<br>";
   
}

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to your problem if you need to access the content of stdClass as an array you can typecast the object variable into array type.

E.g $a=(array)$object;