# foreach stdClass object converted to string

Tags: php, string, object, foreach, stdclass

I am working response from an API which returns data in JSON in a fairly straight forward structure. Pseudo structure is best represented as:

```
services -> service -> options -> option -> suboptions -> option
```

As this is decoded JSON, all of these are stdClass objects. I have a number of foreach statements iterating through the various services and options, which all work without issue. However, when I use a foreach statement at the suboption level, the object is serialized into a string. For your information suboptions has a structure like this.

```
[suboptions] => stdClass Object
 (
    [option] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => SOME_CODE
            [name] => Some Name
        )

 )
```

When using a foreach such as this (where $option is an option in *services -> service -> options ->* **option**):

```
foreach($option->suboptions->option as $suboption) {
  print_r($suboption);
}
```

It outputs

```
SOME_CODESome Name
```

Not the expected

```
stdClass Object
  (
     [code] => SOME_CODE
     [name] => Some Name
  )
```

I am not aware of any reasons foreach would do this in terms of depth or other conditions.
I've tried everything I can think of and searched through SO and can't find any case of this happening. If anyone has any ideas I'd love to hear them! Cheers.

Apologies if it has been answered elsewhere or I am missing something obvious. If I have, it has escaped me thus far.

*Edit:* For those asking it is indeed the AusPost PAC API. Changing over from the DRC as it is being removed ~2014.

Comment: What if you use `var_dump()` instead of `print_r`?

Comment: Is this the Australia Post postage calculation API?

Comment: It is indeed the AusPost PAC API. var_dump() wouldn't give you much else I would imagine...

Comment: @NathanDabkowski I recognised that horrible structure immediately ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is from a response from the [Australia Post postage calculation API](http://auspost.com.au/devcentre/pacpcs.html). This API makes the horrible decision to treat collection instances with only one item as a single value. For example, `service -> options -> option` may be an array or it may be a single *option*.

The easiest way I've found to deal with this is cast the `option` to an array, eg

```
$options = $service->options->option;
if (!is_array($options)) {
    $options = array($options);
}

// now you can loop over it safely
foreach ($options as $option) { ... }
```

You would do the same thing with the sub-options. If you're interested, I've got an entire library that deals with the AusPost API, using [Guzzle](http://guzzlephp.org/) to manage the HTTP side.

Comment: I've seen it do some odd things before, but this one is new! Thanks for pointing it out. They need to do some serious work on it, there are multiple little quirks throughout. I'd love to throw a proper library at it, but the production environment for this is 'limited' at best. Thanks for the offer tho.

Comment: @NathanDabkowski It's nothing fancy. Just a bunch of PHP but it takes care of all the leg work

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, because I don't have that amount of reputation, but I'll try to answer...

I'm assuming you want to remove the stdClass from the PHP array?

If so, then make sure you are using `true` when decoding the JSON.

Example: `$array = json_decode($json, true);`

For more information on stdClass, see this SO post: [What is stdClass in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php)

Again, forgive me if I'm misinterpreting your question, I just wish I could comment...

Answer (score 0):

The values of the last object are not arrays so you would need both the key and value.

```
foreach($option->suboptions->option as $key => $value) {
  echo '<p>KEY:'.$key.' VALUE:'.$value.'</p>';
}
```

Comment: You are correct, but unfortunately this would be a tonne more work to complete with the way the API is designed and what I have to return than the above, but it was something I considered too.